# Send ArrayList<String> from BroadCastReceiver to Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, arraylist, broadcastreceiver, bundle

**Scenario:**

- I have an Alarm scheduled to run on a specified amount of time. Each time is executed, my BroadCastReceiver fires.
- In BroadCastReceiver I do all kind of checks and in the end it results a    ArrayList of plain Strings
- I display an Notification on the Statusbar
- When the user taps on a Notification, I display an Activity. I need in my Activity, the ArrayList to display it on views.

Here is the sample code:

```
public class ReceiverAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         ArrayList<String> notifications = new ArrayList<String>();

         //do the checks, for exemplification I add these values
         notifications.add("This is very important");
         notifications.add("This is not so important");
         notifications.add("This is way too mimportant");

         NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
         //init some values from notificationManager
         Intent intentNotif = new Intent(context, NotificationViewer.class);
         PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentNotif, 0);

         Notification notification = new Notification(icon, text, when);
         notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
         notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }
```

And

```
   public class NotificationViewer extends Activity {


            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.notification_viewer);

                   //HERE I NEED the ArrayList<String> notifications
    }
```

I tried most of the things I have found around, from bundles to putStringArrayListExtra() but nothing worked. In my  Activity I can't find a way to retrieve the data. 
Please help me as I am stuck.

Comment: Are you setting the extras on intentNotif or contentIntent ?

Comment: Extras I've tried on intentNotif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on all comments the working solution is this:

on BroadCastReceiver

```
Intent intentNotif = new Intent(context, NotificationViewer.class);
intentNotif.putStringArrayListExtra("list", notifications);
```

on Activity

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if (b != null) {
    testArrayList= b.getStringArrayList("list");
}
```

This seems to work just fine.

Comment: Ah, good point. I thought `putStringArrayListExtra` was only available with later APIs -I was obviously thinking of something totally different.

Answer (score 1):

As per my suggestion, you may quickly receive it by two ways:

1. Create your custom class which implements `Percelable` and design your own implementation to Write and Read parcelable object.
2. Use `Gson` to serialize an object into single json string, wrap it inside an intent, receive it at other end and de-serialize the Json string back into your desired object type

there might be some other ways, like Serializing the ArrayList into bytes and write it in a file and read it later, but these two are the best ways I can recommend you to handle any type of information. Personally, I like the second one, using Gson to let it handle everything itself.

Answer (score 1):

According to the answer marked as the solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127957/why-the-pendingintent-doesnt-send-back-my-custom-extras-setup-for-the-intent) if you do not specify an action for your pending intent the extras will not be propagated