# Android Notification PendingIntent Extras null

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I am trying to send information from notification to invoked activity, while from my activity I got null.

The code for notification is:

```
private void showNotification() {
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
if (D)
    Log.d(TAG, "Id: " + Id);
resultIntent.putExtra("ineedid", deviceId);

TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(MeterActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
// Bundle tmp = resultIntent.getExtras();
// if (tmp == null) {
// Log.d(TAG, "tmp bundle is null");
// } else {
// long id = tmp.getLong("ineedid", -1);
// Log.d(TAG, "tmp id : " + id);
// }
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
    BLEMessengerService.this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_search)
    .setContentTitle("Event tracker")
    .setContentText("Events received").setOngoing(true)
    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

int mId = R.string.service_notification_start_service;
mNM.notify(mId, mBuilder.getNotification());
}
```

Code for get information from intent in main activity;

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    long deviceID = getIntent().getLongExtra("ineedid",
        -1);
    if (ID == -1) {
    if (D)
        Log.i(TAG_D, "Wrong Id received.");
    finish();
    } else {
    device = dataSource.getDeviceByID(deviceID);
    if (D)
        Log.i(TAG_D, "Get the id.");
    }
} else {
    if (D)
    Log.d(TAG_D, "Bundle is null");
    finish();
}
```

I have verified before the notification get notified, bundle is not null, and it has id in extras.
While, when I tried to fetch it from intent, it's gone. Help.

Comment: I also tried to add "resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);", but no work.

Comment: There a reason you aren't using `resultPendingIntent.getExtras()`?

Comment: I just made those lines to check if my pendingIntent has Extras, and I verified it has what I put there.

Comment: If you are working with FCM, usually the notification is handled by android itself,and hence, your Notification, when clicked does not have extras. For More Info, refer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358462/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-in-background

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just got the answer, 
add line: `resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);`

NOTICE: if you add it as `resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);`
It won't work.

I also tried other flags like, "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK" and "FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED". neither works here.

Comment: I was trying the same thing.
Any clue in the documentation why this flag is needed?
It just says "If set, the activity will not be launched if it is already running at the top of the history stack."

Answer (score 66):

in PendingIntent use this flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` it's work for me

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: If you were only going to use it once at a time, you can use this. But if you need multiple PendingIntents to be valid concurrently, and FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT would leave you with only the most recent intent as valid. Possible solution is intent.flag_activity_new_task

Answer (score 37):

For me, in addition to setting Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP , I had to add a unique action to the intent:

```
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(caller, NotificationActivity.class);

    String xId = getNextUniqueId();
    resultIntent.putExtra("x_id", xId);
    resultIntent.setAction(xId);
    resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

.. without the setAction(..), Extras is null on the Intent received by my NotificationActivity.

This post helps explain it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3128271/2162226

Comment: One of my intents had one extra (a boolean) but another was missing. Specifying an action of any kind fixes it and suddenly both extras are now present! Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

When an activity is launched(when it is first started ) or relaunched(when it's brought to the top of the stack) the `getIntent().getExtra()` won't give `null`. But when the activity is present on the *top of the stack* then on starting that activity with the use of `PendingIntent` would not relaunch the activity(`onCreate()` won't get called) instead `onResume()` would be called. And `getIntent().getExtra()` would return the value which is associated with the intent that started the activity(which is `null`).
*In order to update the intent do the following steps:*

1). Set `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flags in your intent.

> `resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

2). Override `onNewIntent()` in the activity where `getIntent().getExtra()` is called. This method is called by `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

For more info: [See this doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent))

Comment: Clear and correct explanation, this should be the accepted answer

Comment: Excellent! This is the right answer, and comes with a free straightforward explanation.  I'd like to add some more info: in my case, I got one additional problem: the intent persists after first call, meaning that on subsequents app resumes, the behavior programmed repeats because the `Intent` is still the same. To avoid it, I added in `onResume` a `getIntent().removeExtra("the_no-more-desired_extra")` in the right strategical spot.

Answer (score 4):

For me, my Samsung device kept removing the extras from the intent and sometimes even crashed the app. Tried all the combinations but the actual reason for this behaviour was not explicitly adding `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE` flag to the pending intent.

Although, [this is a requirement for Android 12 and above](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#DeclareMutabilityPendingIntent).

```
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                                this, 0,
                                getIntent(),
PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                            )
```

Comment: this really helped, same thing was happening with me , all serialised extras were getting removed and after adding this flag, it worked like a charm

Comment: This worked also for me, but I needed to remove the Intent flags that the accepted answer suggests

Comment: I didn't know we were able to use multiple flags, Kotlin noob  Solved my problem, thanks 

Answer (score 1):

I was working in a local notifications plugin for Unity when I encountered the same problem -> I launched the app, scheduled the local notification, sent the app to background, local notification appeared and, when I clicked on it, app was resumed and `getIntent().getExtras()` was `null`.

In my case, the problem was I was trying to get the extras at the wrong intent. Try to print the intents with a simple toString, at the creation moment and when you get it, to ensure that the received is what you expect.

Also take a look to the [onNewIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) method.

Answer (score 1):

In Pending intent add this two flag

**PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE**

```
val yourDataIntent = Intent(mContext, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
                flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                putExtra("unique_id", "yourId")
                putExtra("type", "yourType")
            }

val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            0,
            yourDataIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ***implicit intent*** to build a PendingIntent, you may get this problem.

previous approach with the issue.

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
intent.data = Uri.parse("deeplink or applink here")
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
intent.putExtra("key", Parcelable)
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, abs(Random.nextInt()), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

based on implicit Intent tried multiple approaches listed above not work for me.

---

here is the approach solved my problem. ***change the Intent from implicit one to an explicit one.***

```
// only diff
val intent = Intent(context, YourIntentDestinationActivity::class.java)
// only diff
intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
intent.data = Uri.parse("deeplink or applink here")
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
intent.putExtra("key", Parcelable)
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, abs(Random.nextInt()), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

hope this works for you.