# Firebase onMessageReceived not called when app in background

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working with Firebase and testing sending notifications to my app from my server while the app is in the background. The notification is sent successfully, it even appears on the notification centre of the device, but when the notification appears or even if I click on it, the onMessageReceived method inside my FCMessagingService is never called.

When I tested this while my app was in the foreground, the onMessageReceived method was called and everything worked fine. The problem occurs when the app is running in the background.

Is this intended behaviour, or is there a way I can fix this?

Here is my FBMessagingService:

```
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class FBMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.i("PVL", "MESSAGE RECEIVED!!");
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody() != null) {
            Log.i("PVL", "RECEIVED MESSAGE: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        } else {
            Log.i("PVL", "RECEIVED MESSAGE: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to the json body, where is your [onTokenRefresh](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream#access-the-registration-token_1) code? Have you completed the [Android setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#set-up-firebase-and-the-fcm-sdk)?

Comment: What do you mean the json body of the notification? Also, my onTokenRefresh code is inside my FirebaseInstanceID service.

Comment: Can you post the sample payload you are sending?

Comment: use https://istudy.io/android-push-notifications-using-firebase-fcm/

Comment: You can also check this thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39046270/google-fcm-getintent-dont-returning-expected-data-when-app-is-in-background-stat

Comment: There are two types of FCM .http://stackoverflow.com/a/37845174/3496570

Comment: I have everything explained in detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45671869/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called/45673611#45673611

Comment: I have that same problem [firebase-messaging-service-not-received-when-app-closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58178693/firebase-messaging-service-not-received-when-app-closed?noredirect=1#comment102739708_58178693)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase

Answer (score 202, accepted):

This is working as intended, notification messages are delivered to your onMessageReceived callback only when your app is in the foreground. If your app is in the background or closed then a notification message is shown in the notification center, and any **data from that message is passed to the intent** that is launched as a result of the user tapping on the notification.

You can specify a `click_action` in your JSON to indicate the intent that should be launched when the notification is tapped by the user. The main activity is used if no click_action is specified.

When the intent is launched you can use the

```
getIntent().getExtras();
```

to retrieve a Set that would include any data sent along with the notification message.

For more on notification message see [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream#sample-receive).

Comment: Is there a way to set the `click_action` when I'm using the Firebase Notification Console?

Comment: ok, but what if the app is killed (no foreground or background)?

Comment: You can test it for yourself. Send a message while your app isn't running. The message should still be delivered to the target phone.

Comment: Click action? from the system tray notification? thats is created by the system... u cannot include pending intent o anything that happends when you click. Do you? In this case? where the notification was  made by the system itself.

Comment: When you are sending notification messages form the REST API you can specify a click_action that determines which intent is fired when the notification (if generated) is tapped by the user. See the REST API reference docs for more: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support

Comment: But how to disable user discard notification? Because if user discard it, it means that all data will be skip... Right?

Comment: Correct! So when sending notification messages to Android, the accompanying data should be data that is enhancing the notification experience. It should not be app critical data, use data messages for data that the application needs even if the user dismisses the notification.

Comment: but still can not get when message is received when app in background.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. If the message does only contain a data and not a notification payload, the message will ALWAYS be delivered to onMessageReceive, if the app is in foreground or not.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

Comment: extra data not parsing when application close and starting an activity by tapping on notification

Comment: I'm using data message (without notification {}). But still, when the app is in background, only clicking the notification tray delivers the data payload in the app. If the message is dismissed by the user, the data never reaches.

Comment: @ArthurThompson  In oreo when app killed, onMessageReceived is not getting called. i just have payload with data only. any update do you have ?

Comment: @ArthurThompson sir could you please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49902190/8027365) regarding **fcm push notification**

Comment: Hi! I tried use `getIntent().getExtras();` but why always return null?

Comment: Don't send notification! Send data only and enclose fields `title` and `message` inside. In this case `onMessageReceived()` will be called on opened and closed app. You'll build a custom notification and translate it using BroadcastReceiver. Full control over any notification in every app state in this case.

Comment: can you provide the code for link for Opening the targetActivity when the app is backgroung. I tried using "click_action" in the payload but it did not work

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase

Comment: Hi @János, I am facing with issue when my app is in background and if notification title is blank in that case in the Notification tray its displaying App Name by default. How to resolve please suggest

Comment: @all Facing same issue when app is in killed state onMessageReceived not getting called and not able to perform action in that state. I am having data payload already in that. Anyone having solution to this ?

Comment: added blog base on @JacksOnF1re, check out https://codingwithtashi.medium.com/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-in-background-18e78280c6cb

Comment: @NiiLaryea yes there is a way, down at the very bottom of the Notification Composer -> Additional options

Answer (score 192):

**Remove `notification` field** completely from your server request. Send **only `data`** and handle it in `onMessageReceived()` otherwise your `onMessageReceived()` will not be triggered when app is in background or killed.

Don't forget to include `"priority": "high"` field in your notification request. According to the documentation: data messages are sent with a normal priority, thus they will not arrive instantly; it could also be the problem.

Here is what I am sending from server

```
{
  "data":{
    "id": 1,
    "missedRequests": 5
    "addAnyDataHere": 123
  },
  "to": "fhiT7evmZk8:APA91bFJq7Tkly4BtLRXdYvqHno2vHCRkzpJT8QZy0TlIGs......",
  "priority": "high"
}
```

So you can receive your data in `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)` like this....let say I have to get id

```
Object obj = message.getData().get("id");
        if (obj != null) {
            int id = Integer.valueOf(obj.toString());
        }
```

Comment: I found that if i send only data message, Then App which is cleared from task manager will not be able to get notification.Is this an intended behavior?

Comment: Does this mean that in the console we can't handle the notification data and if we send a pure HTTP request without the notification section then we can handle notification data ? I started to use Firebase Console expecting I could do this, so I am moving back to HTTP POST notification :-(

Comment: Hi, how to show badge on app icon, when app in background.

Comment: In Oreo when app killed, onMessageReceived is not getting called. i just have payload with data only. any update do you have ?

Comment: @SamirMangroliya I had the same problem. Add `"priority": "high"` to your request. Because data messages are sent with a normal priority, they don't arrive instantly.

Comment: Hi, But when the app is totally closed it does not work

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the scene in my flutter app. This didn't work for me. Can you suggest anything on flutter. Thanks in advance

Comment: I had code in onCreate of Application that was crashing if app was killed and I received notification. Also found out that right directly after you kill the app after running it android studio, you don't receive notification. I opened the app again and killed it again and received notifications. Weird.

Comment: For me, it worked. I just add to put your "priority" field into a android { } dict

Answer (score 69):

this method handleIntent() has been depreciated, so handling a notification can be done as below:

1. Foreground State: The click of the notification will go to the pending Intent's activity which you are providing while creating a notification pro-grammatically as it generally created with data payload of the notification.
2. Background/Killed State - Here, the system itself creates a notification based on notification payload and clicking on that notification will take you to the launcher activity of the application where you can easily fetch Intent data in any of your life-cycle methods.

Comment: Thank you!!! I lost couple of days on this problem and this one saved me.

Comment: really the perfect solution!

Comment: perfect solution i was searching for ..... , u save my day man .........

Comment: What is the `Intent` that this method receives?

Comment: Works! Thank you very much!

Comment: I am handling the notification display logic in handleIntent(Intent intent) , however when the app is in background, 2 notifications are displayed , one that i have created and other by default which contains entire message from notification.

Comment: @Joyson you can avoid twice pushes with remove super.handleIntent(); line from handleIntent

Comment: Awesome, but I don't see any use for `OnMessageReceived` in this case !?

Comment: I can not get payload in handleIntent(Intent intent) method

Comment: i got handleIntent() is static cannot be overridde

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working anymore - handleIntent is final now.

Comment: I'm having com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2 & handleIntent is final now.Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47308155/firebasemessagingservice-11-6-0-handleintent

Comment: handleIntent() is not there in updated gradle(15.0.2). you have to use onMessageReceived() method.

Comment: Please update your solution with some [DEPRECATED] label or similar.

Comment: can you please help me in this problem please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55887711/custom-notification-tone-not-working-when-the-application-is-in-the-background/55894557#55894557

Answer (score 44):

Here is more clear concepts about firebase message. I found it from their support team.

**Firebase has three message types**:

**Notification messages** : Notification message works on background or foreground. When app is in background, Notification messages are delivered to the system tray. If the app is in the foreground, messages are handled by `onMessageReceived()` or `didReceiveRemoteNotification` callbacks. These are essentially what is referred to as Display messages.

**Data messages**: On Android platform, data message can work on background and foreground. The data message will be handled by onMessageReceived(). A platform specific note here would be: On Android, the data payload can be retrieved in the Intent used to launch your activity. To elaborate, if you have `"click_action":"launch_Activity_1"`, you can retrieve this intent through `getIntent()` from only `Activity_1`.

**Messages with both notification and data payloads**: When in the background, apps receive the notification payload in the notification tray, and only handle the data payload when the user taps on the notification. When in the foreground, your app receives a message object with both payloads available. Secondly, the click_action parameter is often used in notification payload and not in data payload. If used inside data payload, this parameter would be treated as custom key-value pair and therefore you would need to implement custom logic for it to work as intended.

Also, I recommend you to use onMessageReceived method (see Data message) to extract the data bundle. From your logic, I checked the bundle object and haven't found expected data content. Here is a reference to a similar case which might provide more clarity.

**From server side, firebase notification should bellow format**:

Server side should send **"notification"** object. Lacks of "notification" object in my `TargetActivity` didn't getting message using `getIntent()`.

Correct message format is given bellow:

```
{
 "data": {
  "body": "here is body",
  "title": "Title"
 },
"notification": {
  "body": "here is body",
  "title": "Title",
  "click_action": "YOUR_ACTION"
 },
 "to": "ffEseX6vwcM:APA91bF8m7wOF MY FCM ID 07j1aPUb"
}
```

For more info visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/39805517

Comment: worth mentioning that "data messages" will not be received if the device is in deep doze mode (introduced in Android 7.0). be careful with those!

Answer (score 32):

I had the same problem. It is easier to use the 'data message' instead of the 'notification'. The data message always load the class onMessageReceived.

In that class you can make your own notification with the notificationbuilder.

Example:

```
 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"),remoteMessage.getData().get("body"));
    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageTitle,String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0 /* request code */, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        long[] pattern = {500,500,500,500,500};

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVibrate(pattern)
                .setLights(Color.BLUE,1,1)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks ..I changed my server code and use "data" instead of  "notification" and now it's working perfect,

Comment: @Koot it working only if app is in foreground not if it is in background. can u help me to trigger this event in both cases??

Comment: @AnantShah how does your POST to the Firebase server looks like?

Comment: There are actually three possible cases here. 1) App in foreground. 2) App in background. 3) App not running. As you say, a 'data' message will be received in the first two cases, but *not* in the third case, when the app is not running. To cater for all three cases, you need to set the 'notification' field in the message. (Also a good idea if you want to support iOS as well as Android clients)

Comment: @SteveMoseley Do you have a link to the documentation where these three cases are described? I always only see "foreground" and "background" mentioned in the docs and thought that background included case "app is not running" - because they advertise like this "send notifications to reengage your users so they use your app again and you make money" <-- That wouldn't make sense if notifications are only received when app is running because then you don't need to "reengage" your users. But what I experience on my real device is just what you describe with these three cases. (emulator works fine)

Comment: Even in the app is not running, i stil get a message from the server on the function onmessagereceived. I agree with you that it is better to use 'notification' if you want to support ios too.

Comment: thank..! I am passing 3 values from backend how to Handel the frontend side

Answer (score 30):

As per Firebase Cloud Messaging documentation-If Activity is in foreground then onMessageReceived will get called. If Activity is in background or closed then notification message is shown in the notification center for app launcher activity.
You can call your customized activity on click of notification if your app is in background by calling rest service api for firebase messaging as:

URL-https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Method Type- POST

```
Header- Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=your api key
```

Body/Payload:

```
{ "notification": {
    "title": "Your Title",
    "text": "Your Text",
     "click_action": "OPEN_ACTIVITY_1" // should match to your intent filter
  },
    "data": {
    "keyname": "any value " //you can get this data as extras in your activity and this data is optional
    },
  "to" : "to_id(firebase refreshedToken)"
}
```

And with this in your app you can add below code in your activity to be called:

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="OPEN_ACTIVITY_1" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Where would I create the intent and have it open a specific activity? I know this registers the OPEN_ACTIVITY_1 intent in the manifest, but where do I actually call it?

Comment: Check this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream#sample-receive

Comment: Should we call an activity from intent-filters? Or start it manually in `onMessageReceived`?

Answer (score 23):

**onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)** method called based on the following cases.

- **FCM Response** With **notification** and **data** block:

```
{
  
"to": "device token list",
  "notification": {
    "body": "Body of Your Notification",
    "title": "Title of Your Notification"
  },
  "data": {
    "body": "Body of Your Notification in Data",
    "title": "Title of Your Notification in Title",
    "key_1": "Value for key_1",
    "image_url": "www.abc.com/xyz.jpeg",
    "key_2": "Value for key_2"
  }
}
```

1. **App in Foreground:**

**onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)** called,  shows  LargeIcon and BigPicture in the notification bar. We can read the content from both  **notification** and **data** block

2. **App in Background:**

**onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)** not called, system tray will receive the message and read body and title from **notification** block and  shows default message and title in the notification bar.

- **FCM Response** With only **data** block:

In this case, removing **notification** blocks from json

```
{
  
"to": "device token list",
  "data": {
    "body": "Body of Your Notification in Data",
    "title": "Title of Your Notification in Title",
    "key_1": "Value for key_1",
    "image_url": "www.abc.com/xyz.jpeg",
    "key_2": "Value for key_2"
  }
}
```

**Solution for calling onMessageReceived()**

1. **App in Foreground:**

**onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)** called,  shows  LargeIcon and BigPicture in the notification bar. We can read the content from both  **notification** and **data** block

2. **App in Background:**

**onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)** called, system tray will not receive the message because of **notification** key is not in the response. Shows  LargeIcon and BigPicture in the notification bar

**Code**

```
 private void sendNotification(Bitmap bitmap,  String title, String 
    message, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent) {

    NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle style = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
    style.bigPicture(bitmap);

    Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = mContext.getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "channel_name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
    Bitmap iconLarge = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),
            R.drawable.mdmlogo);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mdmlogo)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSound)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setStyle(style)
            .setLargeIcon(iconLarge)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);


    notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());


}
```

**Reference Link:**

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: Most important part for people suffering from background issue is to remove the "notification" property from JSON being sent by the server. this solves the problem. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Make sure to change "body" to "message" inside "data".

Answer (score 16):

If app is in the background mode or inactive(killed), and you **click** on **Notification**, you should check for the payload in LaunchScreen(in my case launch screen is MainActivity.java).

So in **MainActivity.java** on **onCreate** check for **Extras**:

```
    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
            Object value = getIntent().getExtras().get(key);
            Log.d("MainActivity: ", "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How can I get notification title, body, and data?

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer. @Md.Tarikul Islam using onMessageReceived() as mentioned in this question.

Answer (score 13):

I got the same issue. If the app is foreground - it triggers my background service where I can update my database based on the notification type.
But, the app goes to the background - the default notification service will be taken care to show the notification to the user.

Here is my solution to identify app in background and trigger your background service,

```
public class FirebaseBackgroundService extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

  private static final String TAG = "FirebaseService";

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "I'm in!!!");

    if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
      for (String key : intent.getExtras().keySet()) {
        Object value = intent.getExtras().get(key);
        Log.e("FirebaseDataReceiver", "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
        if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("gcm.notification.body") && value != null) {
          Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
          Intent backgroundIntent = new Intent(context, BackgroundSyncJobService.class);
          bundle.putString("push_message", value + "");
          backgroundIntent.putExtras(bundle);
          context.startService(backgroundIntent);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:exported="true" android:name=".FirebaseBackgroundService" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Tested this solution in latest android 8.0 version. Thanks

Comment: whare to use this FirebaseBackgroundService class?? @Nagendra Badiganti

Comment: where to use this code public class FirebaseBackgroundService extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver @Nagendra Badiganti

Comment: create a service class in your package and register in your manifest.xml. Make sure that you have the filter for your notifications. Since the service triggers for every GCM notification.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#sample-receive i am following this link, i need to add this class to receive notification . just sending message from firebase first message.. it says completed but not receiving notification @Nagendra Badiganti

Comment: did you add google-services.json in your project root folder?

Comment: Thanks for this answer ! I don't see the chapter on this subject in the firebase link, is there any ? Could you please include your BackgroundSyncJobService class in your answer ?

Comment: `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` is deprecated since API level 26.1.0.

Answer (score 10):

Override the `handleIntent` Method of the `FirebaseMessageService` works for me.

here the code in **C# (Xamarin)**

```
public override void HandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    try
    {
        if (intent.Extras != null)
        {
            var builder = new RemoteMessage.Builder("MyFirebaseMessagingService");

            foreach (string key in intent.Extras.KeySet())
            {
                builder.AddData(key, intent.Extras.Get(key).ToString());
            }

            this.OnMessageReceived(builder.Build());
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleIntent(intent);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        base.HandleIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

and thats the Code in **Java**

```
public void handleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    try
    {
        if (intent.getExtras() != null)
        {
            RemoteMessage.Builder builder = new RemoteMessage.Builder("MyFirebaseMessagingService");

            for (String key : intent.getExtras().keySet())
            {
                builder.addData(key, intent.getExtras().get(key).toString());
            }

            onMessageReceived(builder.build());
        }
        else
        {
            super.handleIntent(intent);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        super.handleIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: handleIntent() is final

Comment: @Ettore How can I invoke the handleIntent function?

Comment: The method is called when you receive the message from Firebase, but you can not override because the method is declared final. (Firebase 11.6.0)

Answer (score 8):

I might be very late here to answers but the official documentation is a bit confusing.

Also it's clearly stated that there are two types of notification

- **Notification message**: Automatically handled by FCM
- **Data message**: Handled by the client app.

No doubt if the server sends a Data message then onMessageReceived() methods definitely get invoked but in the case of Notification message onMessageReceived() method will get invoked only if the app is in the foreground and when the app is in the background the data we are sending is just null.

**Example:**

Lets assume server is sending notification message type:

**A.** In case of Foreground:

- remoteMessage.data["key"] will work

**B.** In case of background:
-remoteMessage.data["key"] will return null
but here if you find the same intent data in defaul activity with getIntent().getExtras().getString("key") will work

**C.** In case of kill:
-remoteMessage.data["key"] will return null
but here if you find the same intent data in defaul activity with getIntent().getExtras().getString("key") will work

Now, let's assume server is sending data message type:

**D.** In case of Foreground:

- remoteMessage.data["key"] will work

**E.** In case of background:

- remoteMessage.data["key"] will work

**F.** In case of kill:

- remoteMessage.data["key"] will work

No doubt data message will always invokes onMessageReceived() method but in case of notification message and app is in background/kill state you can use the solution of **B**. Thanks

I hope it will save everyone's time.

Comment: very useful message, why it is not highlighed in android documents.

Answer (score 8):

I think the answers to tell you change message type to **data** are clear to you.

But sometimes, if you cannot decide your the message type you received and you have to handle it.  I post my method here.  You just implemented FirebaseMessagingService and handle your message in **handlIntent()** method.  From there you could customize your own notification.  You can implement your own method **sendYourNotificatoin**()

```
class FCMPushService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

companion object {
    private val TAG = "FCMPush"
}



override fun handleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    Logger.t(TAG).i("handleIntent:${intent.toString()}")
    val data = intent?.extras as Bundle
    val remoteMessage = RemoteMessage(data)

    if (remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty()) {
        val groupId: String = remoteMessage.data[MESSAGE_KEY_GROUP_ID] ?: ""
        val title = remoteMessage.notification?.title ?: ""
        val body =  remoteMessage.notification?.body ?: ""
        if (title.isNotEmpty() && body.isNotEmpty())
            sendYourNotificatoin(this, title, body, groupId)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: +1 because all the other answers didn't work me. I wasn't receiving the payload or getting onMessageRecieved call because my app was in the foreground. In order to receive the notification payload/data , we need to override handleIntent.
Thankyou for this.

Answer (score 7):

By default the [Launcher Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html) in you app will be launched when your app is in background and you click the notification, if you have any data part with your notifcation you can handle it in the same activity as follows,

```
if(getIntent().getExtras()! = null){
  //do your stuff
}else{
  //do that you normally do
}
```

Comment: If I navigate from mainActivity, how navigate back to particular Activity will work?

Comment: @Uzair getIntent().getExtras() always getting null,Do you have any other solution ?When app is going bacground onMessageReceived method not call

Answer (score 5):

according to the solution from t3h Exi i would like to post the clean code here. Just put it into MyFirebaseMessagingService and everything works fine if the app is in background mode. You need at least to compile com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1

```
 @Override
public void handleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    try
    {
        if (intent.getExtras() != null)
        {
            RemoteMessage.Builder builder = new RemoteMessage.Builder("MyFirebaseMessagingService");

            for (String key : intent.getExtras().keySet())
            {
                builder.addData(key, intent.getExtras().get(key).toString());
            }



           onMessageReceived(builder.build());
        }
        else
        {
            super.handleIntent(intent);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        super.handleIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement your solution, but the handleIntent() method is final in my SDK version (SDK 27), so I cannot override it in my service...

Comment: Yes but thats not my fault or any reason to give -1  !!! Very arrogant. It works until firebase 11.4.2 then google changed it (made this method final). So now you must program your own solution with notification.

Comment: I did not give a -1 but a +1 !

Comment: You save my job :P

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
public void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    try {
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            RemoteMessage.Builder builder = new RemoteMessage.Builder("MyFirebaseMessagingService");
            for (String key : intent.getExtras().keySet()) {
            builder.addData(key, intent.getExtras().get(key).toString());
        }
            onMessageReceived(builder.build());
        } else {
            super.handleIntent(intent);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        super.handleIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

best luck

Comment: handleIntent is no longer used in firebase:11.8.0 and upper.

Answer (score 3):

If app is in background Fire-base by default handling notification But if we want to our custom notification than we have to change our server side, which is responsible for to send our custom data(data payload)

Remove notification payload completely from your server request. Send only Data and handle it in onMessageReceived() otherwise your onMessageReceived will not be triggered when app is in background or killed.

now,your server side code format look like,

```
{
  "collapse_key": "CHAT_MESSAGE_CONTACT",
  "data": {
    "loc_key": "CHAT_MESSAGE_CONTACT",
    "loc_args": ["John Doe", "Contact Exchange"],
    "text": "John Doe shared a contact in the group Contact Exchange",
    "custom": {
      "chat_id": 241233,
      "msg_id": 123
    },
    "badge": 1,
    "sound": "sound1.mp3",
    "mute": true
  }
}
```

**NOTE**: see this line in above code
"text": "John Doe shared a contact in the group Contact Exchange"
in Data payload you should use "text" parameter instead of "body" or "message" parameters for message description or whatever you want to use text.

**onMessageReceived()**

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

        if (remoteMessage == null)
            return;

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
           /* Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());*/
            Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage);

            try {

                Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(params);
                Log.e("JSON_OBJECT", json.toString());


                Log.e(TAG, "onMessageReceived: " + json.toString());

                handleDataMessage(json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue. Based on the answers and references mentioned in this page, here are my two cents on how I resolved my problem with the below approach:

The message format I had earlier was as below:

```
    {
  "notification": {
    "title": "AppName",
    "sound": null,
    "body": "Hey!YouhaveaMessage"
  },
  "data": {
    "param1": null,
    "param2": [
      238
    ],
    "id": 1
  },
  "to": "--the device push token here--"
}
```

I modified the message format to the below:

```
    {
  "data": {
    "title": "AppName",
    "body": "Hey! You have a message",
    "param1": null,
    "param2": [
      238
    ],
    "id": 1
  },
  "priority": "high",
  "to": " — device push token here — "
}
```

Then I retrieved the title, body and all the parameters from the "data" payload itself. This solved the problem and I could then get the OnMessageReceived callback even though the app is in the background.
I wrote a blog post explaining the same issue, you can find it [here](https://gaandlaneeraja.medium.com/android-make-fcm-work-when-the-app-is-in-the-background-8b04991a045e).

Comment: Please, change `“` to `"`. Actually, it's not a valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have fixed the quotation marks now to make those valid JSONs.

Answer (score 3):

```
{
      "notification": {
        "title": "Notification Title",
        "body": "Notification Body",
        "click_action": "ActivityToOpen"
      },
      "data": {
        "key": "value "
      },
      "to": "id"
}
```

If the FCM payload has notification{} block like the above and the app is in the background, the system builds the notification for you with the title and body given in notification{}. When the user clicks on it, the activity mentioned in click_action opens, if nothing is given the default launcher activity opens and data inside the data{} block can be accessed from

```
intent.extras // of the launcher activity
```

If the app is in the foreground the function onMessageReceived() in FirebaseMessagingService() class gets triggered. We will have to build the notification by ourselves and we can access the data as following:

```
val value = message.data.getOrDefault("key", "")
```

If the FCM payload is without notification block{} like following;

```
{ 
    "data": {
    "title": "Notification Title",
     "body": "Notification Body",
    "key": "value "
    },
  "to" : "id"
}
```

The function onMessageReceived() in FirebaseMessagingService() class gets triggered regardless of app being in background or foreground and we will have to build notification by ourselves.

We can access the data as following:

```
    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(message)
        val title = message.data.getOrDefault("title", "")
        val body = message.data.getOrDefault("body", "")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just call this in your MainActivity's onCreate Method :

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
           // Call your NotificationActivity here..
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotificationActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: If I navigate from mainActivity, how navigate back to particular Activity will work?

Answer (score 2):

FirebaseMessagingService has

```
public void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (!"com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE".equals(action) && !"com.google.firebase.messaging.RECEIVE_DIRECT_BOOT".equals(action)) {
        if ("com.google.firebase.messaging.NEW_TOKEN".equals(action)) {
            this.onNewToken(intent.getStringExtra("token"));
        } else {
            Log.d("FirebaseMessaging", "Unknown intent action: " + intent.getAction());
        }
    } else {
        this.handleMessageIntent(intent);
    }

}
```

you can simply override this function in your own service class which extends FirebaseMessagingService.

this.handleMessageIntent(intent); -> handles the notification when app is closed/background. You can remove this line and use the functions which are used in overriden onMessageRecieved() method to show custom layout. so you show your own custom layout both background/foreground.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue(app doesn't want to open on notification click if app is in background or closed), and the problem was an invalid `click_action` in notification body, try removing or changing it to something valid.

Answer (score 1):

The point which deserves highlighting is that you have to use data message - **data key only** - to get onMessageReceived handler called even when the app is in background. You shouldn't have any other notification message key in your payload, otherwise the handler won't get triggered if the app is in background.

It is mentioned (but not so emphasized in FCM documentation) here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

> Use your app server and FCM server API: Set the **data key only**. Can be
>   either collapsible or non-collapsible.

Answer (score 1):

The backend I'm working with is using **Notification messages** and not Data messages. So after reading all the answers I tried to retrieve the extras from the bundle of the intent that comes to the launched activity.
But no matter which keys I tried to retrieve from `getIntent().getExtras();`, the value was always null.

However, I finally found a way to send data using **Notification messages** and retrieve it from the intent.

The key here is to add the **data payload** to the Notification message.

Example:

```
{
    "data": {
        "message": "message_body",
        "title": "message_title"
    },
    "notification": {
        "body": "test body",
        "title": "test title"
    },
    "to": "E4An.."
}
```

After you do this, you will be able to get your info in this way:

`intent.getExtras().getString("title")`
will be `message_title`

and 
`intent.getExtras().getString("message")`
will be `message_body`

[Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is related to showing Big Image i.e. if you are sending push notification with an image from firebase console and it displays the image only if the app in the foreground. The solution for this problem is to send a push message with only data field. Something like this:

```
{ "data": { "image": "https://static.pexels.com/photos/4825/red-love-romantic-flowers.jpg", "message": "Firebase Push Message Using API" "AnotherActivity": "True" }, "to" : "device id Or Device token" }
```

Comment: you lost comma before "AnotherActivity". My android vibrates but really nothing shown (no text, no image, no push).

Answer (score 1):

When message is received and your app is in background the notification is sent to the extras intent of the main activity.

You can check the extra value in the oncreate() or onresume() function of the main activity.

You can check for the fields like data, table etc ( the one specified in the notification)

for example I sent using data as the key

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if (getIntent().getStringExtra("data")!=null){
            fromnotification=true;
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
            i.putExtra("notification","notification");
            startActivity(i);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and did some more digging on this. When the app is in the background, a **notification message** is sent to the system tray, BUT a **data message** is sent to `onMessageReceived()`
See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream#monitor-token-generation_3
and https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

To ensure that the message you are sending, the docs say, "*Use your app server and FCM server API: Set the data key only. Can be either collapsible or non-collapsible.*"
See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of messages: notification messages and data messages.
If you only send data message, that is without notification object in your message string. It would be invoked when your app in background.

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer of @Mahesh Kavathiya. For my case, in server code has only like this:

```
{
"notification": {
  "body": "here is body",
  "title": "Title",
 },
 "to": "sdfjsdfonsdofoiewj9230idsjkfmnkdsfm"
}
```

You need to change to:

```
{
 "data": {
  "body": "here is body",
  "title": "Title",
  "click_action": "YOUR_ACTION"
 },
"notification": {
  "body": "here is body",
  "title": "Title"
 },
 "to": "sdfjsdfonsdofoiewj9230idsjkfmnkdsfm"
}
```

Then, in case app in Background, the default activity intent extra will get **"data"**

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

That is the intended behavior, you need to set **click_action** in firebase notification data set to be able to receive data from background.

**See updated answer here:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73724040/7904082

Answer (score -1):

There are **2 types** of *Firebase* push-notifications:

1- Notification message(Display message) -> 
-- 1.1 If you choose this variant, the OS will create it self a notification if app is in **Background** and will pass the data in the `intent`. Then it's up to the client to handle this data.

-- 1.2 If the app is in **Foreground** then the notification it will be received via `callback-function` in the `FirebaseMessagingService` and it's up to the client to handle it.

2- Data messages(up to 4k data) -> These messages are used to send only data to the client(silently) and it's up to the client to handle it for both cases background/foreground via callback-function in `FirebaseMessagingService`

This is according official docs:https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Answer (score -3):

Just override the OnCreate method of FirebaseMessagingService. It is called when your app is in background:

```
public override void OnCreate()
{
    // your code
    base.OnCreate();
}
```

Comment: This answer could be more useful if you could add an explanation, and link to some documentation. Can you please tell us how this is supposed to help?

Comment: @kilokahn Can you explain to me what you do you not understand? the indicated method must be inserted in the code that is part of the question and fully answers the question. The code is for Xamarin, but you can simply convert in java.

Comment: AFAIK The official documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) does not talk about overriding OnCreate in a service extending FirebaseMessagingService - if you have access to documentation that does, perhaps you can share a link? 

Also, from your answer, it is not clear how overriding onCreate solves the problem of onMessageReceived not getting called when the notification is clicked - hence the request for more information.

Comment: The documentation does not mention the override of the OnCreate method, but it works because I'm using it in production. The code that you would like to insert in the onMessageReceived method and which obviously serves to do some background operations can be performed on OnCreate.

Comment: In that case, elaborating on the fact that it somehow worked for you may prove more helpful than just listing the solution. 

Also, undocumented behaviour is likely to arbitrarily stop working with updates, and someone using them has to be prepared to rework their code when it does. This disclaimer needs to be put in.