# How can I send a Firebase Cloud Messaging notification without use the Firebase Console?

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm starting with the new Google service for the notifications, `Firebase Cloud Messaging`.

Thanks to this code https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging I was able to send notifications from my **Firebase User Console** to my Android device.

Is there any API or way to send a notification without use the Firebase console? I mean, for example, a PHP API or something like that, to create notifications from my own server directly.

Comment: Where are you hosting your server to send notifications?

Comment: @David Corral, Check my answer for same. 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/38992689/2122328

Comment: Have written a spring app to send FCM notifications incase you wish to see how it works -> https://github.com/aniket91/WebDynamo/blob/master/src/com/osfg/controllers/FCMSender.java

Comment: You can use retrofit to mesage davice to device. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435750/how-to-send-device-to-device-messages-using-firebase-cloud-messaging/41913555#41913555

Comment: Read this blogpost for more details   http://developine.com/how-to-send-firebase-push-notifications-from-app-server-tutorial/

Comment: @David I have created a chat application in which when a user sends a message to receiver the receiver should get a notification message. In this case how can I use your answer? So what should I have to give the value for the field " to " ?

Comment: You can view bellow link. It has Spring java implementation
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51172021/3073945

Answer (score 281, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Messaging has a server-side APIs that you can call to send messages. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server.

Sending a message can be as simple as using `curl` to call a HTTP end-point. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#implementing-http-connection-server-protocol

```
curl -X POST --header "Authorization: key=<API_ACCESS_KEY>" \
    --Header "Content-Type: application/json" \
    https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \
    -d "{\"to\":\"<YOUR_DEVICE_ID_TOKEN>\",\"notification\":{\"title\":\"Hello\",\"body\":\"Yellow\"}}"
```

You can all this REST API from within any environment, but there are dedicated so-called Admin SDKs for many platforms listed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#firebase-admin-sdk-for-fcm).

Comment: How can I get the device id on iOS? Is it the device token we get on *didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData* or the long one we get with *FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()* ?

Comment: Frank I followed the guide at firebase docs and codelabs for adding push notifications on a progressive webapp and using POstman to post a http request, yet i keep getting 401 error. ANy suggestions. I'm copying my server key directly from my firebase console.

Comment: how to send to all users rather than a particular users or topics?

Comment: I got this error message back in one of my early tries with the CURL snippet: Field "priority" must be a JSON number: 10.  After I removed the quotation marks from the 10 at the end, it worked.

Comment: @vinbhai4u Do you get the answer? I am also stuck at that. How to send that to all application users?

Comment: @jasan - Did you find the answer for when using Postman? I'm stuck at the same place with a 401 error. I'm providing the correct Headers as far as I know. Thanks

Comment: @user1203605 I used this guide https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client to add FCM to my webapp. and then used this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message to send the message through server or Postman and it works

Comment: @jasan - Thanks for your help, I've got it working. I also found that for Postman, when you enter the Key/Value pair, it expects Authorization in the Key and the Key/Value pair in the Value e.g. key=AIzaSyCFF...nNhHHz. (just in case anyone else turns up here with the same issue).

Comment: @jasan Thanks for the links. Do I really need to import the firebase js files just to be able to send push notifications? Like others I also am stuck at 401 errors...

Comment: @Spock you dont need to import anything other than your FCM Server Token(Server Key is being depreciated) , found in firebase console in order to send FCM messages. I think you are referring to the the following imports, maybe: `importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-messaging.js')`    then the answer is Yes. Those imports are needed in the service worker file , in order to handle FCm in foreground/background.

Comment: @jasan thank you.. I just find it so weird, because the Web Push protocol is not provider dependend, and should work with all browsers that support the protocol.. I'm super confused, because I hear different things all the time, while the implementation details in the browsers and endpoints change nonstop. I really don't want to import vendor-specific stuff into my service worker code :(

Comment: how can i send a notification without using the console and also without using php i mean just android , for exemple in my case when user like photo of his friend the other user recive a notification fi the app closed or in background ?

Comment: There is no way to directly send messages from one Android device to another Android device. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435750/how-to-send-device-to-device-messages-using-firebase-cloud-messaging, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432243/how-to-send-device-to-device-notification-by-using-fcm-without-using-xmpp-or-any or one of the others in this page: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebase+device+to+device

Comment: @vinbhai4u you can loop through a set of device tokens and send push notifications to each individual device token. For example, if you have an array of device tokens, just loop through each index and send a push notification to the device token at that index.

Comment: Read this blog post for more complete guide. http://developine.com/how-to-send-firebase-push-notifications-from-app-server-tutorial/

Comment: Sir, can this be used to send all the devices and web browsers?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, Hi I have created a chat application in which when a user sends a message to receiver the receiver should get a notification message. In this case how can I use your answer? So what should I have to give the value for the field " to " ?

Comment: what is thsi -> YOUR_DEVICE_ID_TOKEN

Comment: @vinbhai4u for send to all users, is needed to subscribe theme to 'all' topic. and so send to '/topics/all'

Comment: @vinbhai4u to send a message to more than 1 token, use the registration_ids parameter which takes an array of not more than 100 reg tokens. See documentation here.
firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref. Note that you cannot use the `to` and `registration_ids` parameters at the same time. You cannot send to more than 100 tokens using this method. To achieve this, you should send in batches.

Answer (score 68):

This works using CURL

```
function sendGCM($message, $id) {


    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    $fields = array (
            'registration_ids' => array (
                    $id
            ),
            'data' => array (
                    "message" => $message
            )
    );
    $fields = json_encode ( $fields );

    $headers = array (
            'Authorization: key=' . "YOUR_KEY_HERE",
            'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init ();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );

    $result = curl_exec ( $ch );
    echo $result;
    curl_close ( $ch );
}

?>
```

`$message` is your message to send to the device

`$id` is the **devices registration token**

`YOUR_KEY_HERE` is your Server API Key (or Legacy Server API Key)

Comment: Firebase Console have no save push messaging data into https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send?

Comment: to send push notification to browser from where i can get device registration id ?

Comment: this works perfectly but, because of the long text I am getting `{"multicast_id":3694931298664346108,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MessageTooBig"}]}`. What can be done to fix this?

Comment: @AlishaLamichhane Is your message bigger than 4096 bytes? If not you can base64 encode your message (there might be something wrong with the text). If it is bigger than 4096 bytes... well, that's the FCM limit.

Comment: `to` replaces `registration_ids`

Comment: if you are willing to handle firebase messages even in app killed mode you should add 
''notification' => array(
                "body" => 'Notification body',
                'title' => $message
            ),'

Answer (score 63):

Use a service api.

URL: `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`

Method Type: `POST`

Headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: key=your api key
```

Body/Payload:

```json
{
   "notification": {
      "title": "Your Title",
      "text": "Your Text",
      "click_action": "OPEN_ACTIVITY_1"
   },
   "data": {
      "<some_key>": "<some_value>"
   },
   "to": "<device_token>"
}
```

And with this in your app you can add below code in your activity to be called:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="OPEN_ACTIVITY_1" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Also check the answer on [Firebase onMessageReceived not called when app in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358462/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-in-background/37599088#37599088)

Comment: Ankit, I can send to specific device id. However, I can't send to all. What I've to put `"to" : "to_id(firebase refreshedToken)"` instead of device id? `"all"` is not working at all. I'm using C# `WebRequest` to send notification. @AshikurRahman your suggestion also welcome. I'm struggling and searching since 3-4 days.

Comment: Nevermind. I found the solution. to : "/topics/all" will send notifications to all devices or if you want to target only IOS replace all with ios and for android, replace with `android'. These are the default topics set. I guess.

Comment: http://developine.com/how-to-send-firebase-push-notifications-from-app-server-tutorial/

Comment: Read this blogpost for more details - > http://developine.com/how-to-send-firebase-push-notifications-from-app-server-tutorial/

Comment: @Ankit, Hi, could you please specify how to get the target device's id?

Comment: @AnandRaj https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787373/firebase-fcm-how-to-get-token You can get the token and save in your storage(Database) on server.

Comment: @AnkitAdlakha what if we don't want to use the firebase API. what are my options ?

Comment: how can we send channel id? any suggestion? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 50):

> **Examples using curl**

**Send messages to specific devices**

To send messages to specific devices, set the  to the registration token for the specific app instance

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization:key=<Your Api key>"  -X POST -d '{ "data": { "score": "5x1","time": "15:10"},"to" : "<registration token>"}' https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

**Send messages to topics**

here the topic is : /topics/foo-bar

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization:key=<Your Api key>"  -X POST -d '{ "to": "/topics/foo-bar","data": { "message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!"}}' https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

**Send messages to device groups**

Sending messages to a device group is very similar to sending messages to an individual device. Set the to parameter to the unique notification key for the device group

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization:key=<Your Api key>"  -X POST -d '{"to": "<aUniqueKey>","data": {"hello": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Device Group Message!"}}' https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

> **Examples using Service API**

API URL : `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`

Headers

```
Content-type: application/json
Authorization:key=<Your Api key>
```

Request Method : `POST`

**Request Body**

Messages to specific devices

```
{
  "data": {
    "score": "5x1",
    "time": "15:10"
  },
  "to": "<registration token>"
}
```

Messages to topics

```
{
  "to": "/topics/foo-bar",
  "data": {
    "message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!"
  }
}
```

Messages to device groups

```
{
  "to": "<aUniqueKey>",
  "data": {
    "hello": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Device Group Message!"
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did you find the endpoint url  https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send , its no wherw mentioned in firebase doc?

Comment: You can find that in this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server

Comment: @J.R. I have created a chat application in which when a user sends a message to receiver the receiver should get a notification message. In this case how can I use your answer? So what should I have to give the value for the field " to " ?

Comment: @ Anad Raj refer "Send messages to specific devices" in my answer

Answer (score 25):

As mentioned by Frank, you can use Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) HTTP API to trigger push notification from your own back-end. But you won't be able to

1. send notifications to a Firebase User Identifier (UID) and
2. send notifications to user segments (targeting properties & events like you can on the user console).

Meaning: you'll have to store FCM/GCM registration ids (push tokens) yourself or use FCM topics to subscribe users. Keep also in mind that **FCM is not an API for Firebase Notifications**, it's a lower-level API without scheduling or open-rate analytics. Firebase Notifications is build on top on FCM.

Answer (score 12):

## Introduction

I compiled most of the answers above and updated the variables based on the [FCM HTTP Connection Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#implementing-http-connection-server-protocol) to curate a solution that works with FCM in 2021. Credit to [Hamzah Malik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39058440/7145285) for his very insightful answer above.

### Prerequisites

First, ensure that you have connected your project with Firebase and that you have set up all dependencies on your app. If you haven't, first head over to the [FCM Config docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)

If that is done, you will also need to copy your project's server response key from the API. Head over to your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/), click on the project you're working on and then navigate to;

```
Project Settings(Setting wheel on upper left corner) -> Cloud Messaging Tab -> Copy the Server key
```

### Configuring your PHP Backend

I compiled Hamzah's answer with [Ankit Adlakha's API call structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37599206/7145285) and the FCM Docs to come up with the PHP function below:

```
function sendGCM() {
  // FCM API Url
  $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

  // Put your Server Response Key here
  $apiKey = "YOUR SERVER RESPONSE KEY HERE";

  // Compile headers in one variable
  $headers = array (
    'Authorization:key=' . $apiKey,
    'Content-Type:application/json'
  );

  // Add notification content to a variable for easy reference
  $notifData = [
    'title' => "Test Title",
    'body' => "Test notification body",
    'click_action' => "android.intent.action.MAIN"
  ];

  // Create the api body
  $apiBody = [
    'notification' => $notifData,
    'data' => $notifData,
    "time_to_live" => "600" // Optional
    'to' => '/topics/mytargettopic' // Replace 'mytargettopic' with your intended notification audience
  ];

  // Initialize curl with the prepared headers and body
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($apiBody));

  // Execute call and save result
  $result = curl_exec ( $ch );

  // Close curl after call
  curl_close ( $ch );

  return $result;
}
```

### Customizing your notification push

To submit the notifications via tokens, use `'to' => 'registration token'`

### What to expect

I set up the function in my website back-end and tested it on Postman. If your configuration was successful, you should expect a response similar to the one below;

```
{"message":"{"message_id":3061657653031348530}"}
```

Answer (score 7):

this solution from [this link](https://www.ma-no.org/en/programming/php/send-push-notification-to-users-using-firebase-messaging-service-in-php) helped me a lot. you can check it out.

The curl.php file with those line of instruction can work.

```
<?php 
// Server key from Firebase Console define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AAAA----FE6F' );
$data = array("to" => "cNf2---6Vs9", "notification" => array( "title" => "Shareurcodes.com", "body" => "A Code Sharing Blog!","icon" => "icon.png", "click_action" => "http://shareurcodes.com"));
$data_string = json_encode($data);
echo "The Json Data : ".$data_string;
$headers = array ( 'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY, 'Content-Type: application/json' );
$ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo "<p>&nbsp;</p>";
echo "The Result : ".$result;
```

Remember `you need to execute curl.php file using another browser ie not from the browser that is used to get the user token. You can see notification only if you are browsing another website.`

Answer (score 6):

First you need to get a token from android and then you can call this php code and you can even send data for further actions in your app.

```
 <?php

// Call .php?Action=M&t=title&m=message&r=token
$action=$_GET["Action"];


switch ($action) {
    Case "M":
         $r=$_GET["r"];
        $t=$_GET["t"];
        $m=$_GET["m"];

        $j=json_decode(notify($r, $t, $m));

        $succ=0;
        $fail=0;

        $succ=$j->{'success'};
        $fail=$j->{'failure'};

        print "Success: " . $succ . "<br>";
        print "Fail   : " . $fail . "<br>";

        break;


default:
        print json_encode ("Error: Function not defined ->" . $action);
}

function notify ($r, $t, $m)
    {
    // API access key from Google API's Console
        if (!defined('API_ACCESS_KEY')) define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'Insert here' );
        $tokenarray = array($r);
        // prep the bundle
        $msg = array
        (
            'title'     => $t,
            'message'     => $m,
           'MyKey1'       => 'MyData1',
            'MyKey2'       => 'MyData2', 

        );
        $fields = array
        (
            'registration_ids'     => $tokenarray,
            'data'            => $msg
        );

        $headers = array
        (
            'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
        $result = curl_exec($ch );
        curl_close( $ch );
        return $result;
    }


?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is the working code in my project using CURL.

```
<?PHP
//Avoid keys confusions!
//firebase Cloud Messaging have 3 different keys: 
//API_KEY, SERVER_KEY and PUSH_KEY ... here we need SERVER_KEY

// SERVER access key from Google firebase Console    
define( 'SERVER_ACCESS_KEY', 'YOUR-SERVER-ACCESS-KEY-GOES-HERE' );


 $registrationIds = array( $_GET['id'] );

  // prep the bundle
 $msg = array
 (
   'message'    => 'here is a message. message',
    'title'     => 'This is a title. title',
    'subtitle'  => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
    'tickerText'    => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
 );

 $fields = array
 (
    // use this to method if want to send to topics
    // 'to' => 'topics/all'
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
     'notification'         => $msg
 );

 $headers = array
 (
    'Authorization: key=' . SERVER_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
 );

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
 curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
 curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
 curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
 curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
 curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
 $result = curl_exec($ch );
 curl_close( $ch );

 echo $result;
```

Comment: define is missing in API_ACCESS_KEY  line .  Also google cloud messaging old  url is deprecated  use   https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Comment: also instead `API_ACCESS_KEY ` must be `SERVER_ACCESS_KEY ` because firebase messaging have 3 keys. 1. `API_KEY` 2. `PUSH_KEY` 3. `SERVER_KEY` .... and that can generate confusions ... I have made a edit to your answer. Tested and working Today 22 December 2022

Answer (score 4):

Works in 2020

```
$response = Http::withHeaders([
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization'=> 'key='. $token,
        ])->post($url, [
            'notification' => [
                'body' => $request->summary,
                'title' => $request->title,
                'image' => 'http://'.request()->getHttpHost().$path,
                
            ],
            'priority'=> 'high',
            'data' => [
                'click_action'=> 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
                
                'status'=> 'done',
                
            ],
            'to' => '/topics/all'
        ]);
```

Comment: Works in 2021 also. Thanks. I was using 'text' instead of 'body'

Answer (score 3):

You can use for example a PHP script for Google Cloud Messaging (GCM). Firebase, and its console, is just on top of GCM.

I found this one on github:
https://gist.github.com/prime31/5675017

Hint: This PHP script results in a [android notification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json).

Therefore: Read [this answer from Koot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37471326/6161100) if you want to receive and show the notification in Android.

Answer (score 2):

Notification or data message can be sent to firebase base cloud messaging server using FCM HTTP v1 API endpoint.
https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/zoftino-stores/messages:send.

You need to generate and download private key of service account using Firebase console and generate access key using google api client library. Use any http library to post message to above end point, below code shows posting message using OkHTTP. You can find complete server side and client side code at [firebase cloud messaging and sending messages to multiple clients using fcm topic example](http://www.zoftino.com/android-notification-data-messages-from-app-server-using-firebase-cloud-messaging)

If a specific client message needs to sent, you need to get firebase registration key of the client, see [sending client or device specific messages to FCM server example](http://www.zoftino.com/sending-device-specific-push-notification-message-using-firebase-cloud-messaging)

```
String SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging";
String FCM_ENDPOINT
     = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/zoftino-stores/messages:send";

GoogleCredential googleCredential = GoogleCredential
    .fromStream(new FileInputStream("firebase-private-key.json"))
    .createScoped(Arrays.asList(SCOPE));
googleCredential.refreshToken();
String token = googleCredential.getAccessToken();



final MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");

OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url(FCM_ENDPOINT)
    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; UTF-8")
    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
    .post(RequestBody.create(mediaType, jsonMessage))
    .build();


Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
    log.info("Message sent to FCM server");
}
```

Comment: My friend, https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/zoftino-stores/messages:send this link seems to be expired!

Comment: You need to use your google project url, not that one, replace "zotino-stores" with your project name

Answer (score 2):

If you're using PHP, I recommend using the PHP SDK for Firebase: [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html). For an easy configuration you can follow these steps:

Get the project credentials json file from Firebase ([Initialize the sdk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk)) and include it in your project.

Install the SDK in your project. I use composer:

```
composer require kreait/firebase-php ^4.35
```

Try any example from the [Cloud Messaging session](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cloud-messaging.html#cloud-messaging) in the SDK documentation:

```
use Kreait\Firebase;
use Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\CloudMessage;

$messaging = (new Firebase\Factory())
->withServiceAccount('/path/to/firebase_credentials.json')
->createMessaging();

$message = CloudMessage::withTarget(/* see sections below */)
    ->withNotification(Notification::create('Title', 'Body'))
    ->withData(['key' => 'value']);

$messaging->send($message);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Go to cloud Messaging select:  Server key



function sendGCM($message, $deviceToken) {

    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $fields = array (
            'registration_ids' => array (
                $id
            ),
            'data' => array (
                "title" =>  "Notification title",
                "body" =>  $message,
            )
    );
    $fields = json_encode ( $fields );
    $headers = array (
        'Authorization: key=' . "YOUR_SERVER_KEY",
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    $ch = curl_init ();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );
    $result = curl_exec ( $ch );
    echo $result;

    curl_close ($ch);
}
```

Comment: replace this line:
 'data' => array ( 
 with 
'notification' => array (

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use Firebase cloud functions, which is for me the easier way to implement your push notifications.
[firebase/functions-samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications)

Comment: I agree... But unfortunately we can't use it any longer due to need to make a billing account first. Do you think I can call the same code from my personal nodeJs server?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send push notifications from android check out my blog post

[Send Push Notifications from 1 android phone to another with out server.](https://androidredman.wordpress.com/2017/08/27/send-push-notifications-from-1-android-phone-to-another-with-out-server/)

sending push notification is nothing but a post request  to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

code snippet using volley:

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
 try {
 JSONObject userData=new JSONObject();
 userData.put("title","your title");
 userData.put("body","your body");

json.put("data",userData);
json.put("to", receiverFirebaseToken);
 }
 catch (JSONException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", json, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
 @Override
 public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

Log.i("onResponse", "" + response.toString());
 }
 }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
 @Override
 public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

}
 }) {
 @Override
 public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
 params.put("Authorizationey=" + SERVER_API_KEY);
 params.put("Content-Typepplication/json");
 return params;
 }
 };
 MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```

I suggest you all to check out my blog post for complete details.

Comment: http://developine.com/how-to-send-firebase-push-notifications-from-app-server-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Using Firebase Console you can send message to all users based on application package.But with CURL or PHP API its not possible.

Through API You can send notification to specific device ID or subscribed users to selected topic or subscribed topic users.

```
Get a view on following link. It will help you.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message
```

Comment: Yes you can also with PHP curl see https://gist.github.com/prime31/5675017 (BUT Read all comments in the above address because need 2 litle modifications: 1 url = https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send 2. instead 'data' must write 'notification'. Tested and working OK