# Android Notification to country specific users

Tags: firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an android application. I want to send some notification to the user in a particular country. For example I want to send notification to US users only.
    I am trying to use FCM(Firebase cloud messagging) for the same but I can not find any option in user property to select country.
    Someone please tell me how to do that.

Comment: You can send messages to such an audience from the Firebase Notifications console. You cannot (yet) send such audience-targeted messages programmatically. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37995870/how-to-send-firebase-notifications-to-audience-via-http/37997963#37997963

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating Audience based on Country, and then sending notification to **User segment** with setting the Audience.

You can check out this [link](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6394759).

Note: Go for User segment in above mentioned link.