# Notifications with Firebase from web

Tags: firebaseui, firebase-notifications

I have been working on an Android application and my customer that will use it want to send notifications is there any way to send notifications from a Web UI other than firebase console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no public API to send Firebase Notifications. The Firebase Console is the only place for that. We're considering adding an API, which you could then use to build your own web site for your customer.

See [How to send firebase notifications to audience via HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37995870/how-to-send-firebase-notifications-to-audience-via-http)