# 400 error when I don't provide a "to" parameter using Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, okhttp, firebase-notifications

I'm trying to send a downstream push notification from the android client **for practice only**.

However, with this code:

```
private void send() {
    String urlString = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    JSONObject jsonObjects = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObjects.put("title", titleET.getText().toString());
        jsonObjects.put("body", textET.getText().toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, jsonObjects.toString());
    Request req = new Request.Builder()
            .url(urlString)
            .post(body)
            .addHeader("Authorization","key=censored")
            .build();
    try {
        Response res = client.newCall(req).execute();
        if (!res.isSuccessful()) {
            throw new UnknownError("Error: " + res.code() + " " + res.body().string());
        }
        Log.d("MainActivity", res.body().toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        send();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm not doing

```
jsonObjects.put("to","something");
```

That's because I don't want to send it to someone specifically, but to the whole application. If I don't put a "to" into the json, I get an error.

So, how can I send it to my whole application?

Answer (score 1):

You must always specify either a [device token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_specific_devices), a [device group id](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_device_groups) or a [topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_topics). There is no option to send untargeted messages with Firebase Cloud Messaging.

You send notifications to all users of one app in a project from the Firebase Notifications console. But [there is no public API to call this functionality from your own code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38397243/notifications-with-firebase-from-web/38399813#38399813).