# Is it possible to send automatically push notification to android app by using Google Analytics for Firebase Triggers on "app_remove" event

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send a push notification when user is going to uninstall my Android app. My idea is to use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) and [Google Analytics for Firebase Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/analytics-events). In order to be able to use triggers I have been marked "app_remove" event as conversion in Firebase Console of my app. It is possible send notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging triggered by a Firebase function as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091560/send-push-notifications-in-firebase-using-functions-to-analytics-audiences), but when my app is uninstalled It will not be able to show incoming message from FCM as a push notification. It is possible to setup the incoming message to be displayed as push notification even my app is uninstalled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *It is possible to setup the incoming message to be displayed as push notification even my app is uninstalled?*

Not possible. 
When your app is uninstalled, the corresponding registration token tied to that specific app instance is also invalidated.

The registration token is what FCM uses to send messages to the corresponding device, if invalidated, FCM will no longer have any way to send messages to that device.