# FCM console push works but server push does not

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

GCM was working fine but now fcm do not recive any notification if it was sent by server it only work if o send from firebase console I am almost sure the problem is in array form i have in app:

```
        String messageBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
```

and in php:

```
        $fields = array(
        'registration_ids'  => $this->devices,
        'data'              => array( "message" => $message ),
    );
```

what do you think please

Comment: is the FCM app using the same Project / Sender-ID as GCM version of your app? You can either migrate the old project to a "firebase project" from the firebase console, or register the FCM app for a secondary sender via FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken("sender2", "FCM")

also the data-payload of the message is available in remoteMessage.getData() not remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody().
The second field is a for the "notification" payload.

Comment: yes its not a sender-Id issue, so it should be getData() only or getData("message")? whith GCM I used getString("message") and work fime

Comment: getData() will return a Map<String, String> object where you can access the key/values you set in the data payload. In your case you should use getData().get("message") 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.html

Comment: aha nice, but then what about the notifications that comes from the firebase console would the app be able to recive without .getNotification().getBody();?

Comment: The notifications that come from the console can only be a display-message. Which means that if the app is in background it will automatically display a notification-message. If the app is in foreground the onMessageReceive() method will be invoked and you can read the content of the notification via remoteMessage.getNotification().get*
PS: while you can only send display-messages, those messages can include a "data" payload. See the "advanced options" in the Web Console.
Do these comments address the original question? If so I will move them to an answer.

Comment: can you ask your question obviously?

Comment: @Diego actually yes its very valuable informations about notifications system. rewrite it as an answer so i can accept it

Comment: @Edalat the problem is setting the the right message parser code for that server code

Comment: this could be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371990/how-can-i-send-a-firebase-cloud-messaging-notification-without-use-the-firebase?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question you are sending a **data-message**, which is a message with a payload like: 
`{"registration_ids" : ["token1"], "data" : { "key1" : "value1"}}`

To receive the `data` payload (in the example: key1:value1), the client app should to use:

```
String value1 = remoteMessage.getData().get("key1");
```

FCM also supports **display-messages**.
Example: 
`{"registration_ids" : ["token1"], "notification" : { "body" : "hello"}}`
These messages are automatically displayed when the app is in background.
 And they call `onMessageReceived()` only if the app is already open and in foreground.
In this second case you can access the field of the original notification via: `remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()`

Display messages can also include a `{"data" : { "key1" : "value1"}}`.
If the app is in foreground it can access these values like a data-message.
If the app in bakground you need to wait until the user click the notification and starts an activity.
At that point you can access the data via: `getIntent().getExtras()`

PS: the notifications sent via Firebase Web Console are only display-messages.