# Firebase Cloud Messaging with Ionic app not working

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing Android and iOS app using Ionic framework (Web technologies) and I want to add Push Notifications with the help of the new Firebase feature, FCM.

But I'm facing this issue while deploying on a device:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.  ionic-js-sidemenu1      1
>   Error       FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.    ionic-js-sidemenu1      1
>   Error       * What went wrong:  ionic-js-sidemenu1      1
>   Error       A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.  ionic-js-sidemenu1      1
>   Error       > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.    ionic-js-sidemenu1      1
>   Error        > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0.  ionic-js-sidemenu1      1
>   Error        Searched in the following locations:   ionic-js-sidemenu1      1
>   Error        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/9.2.0/firebase-core-9.2.0.pom ionic-js-sidemenu1      1
>   Error        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/9.2.0/firebase-core-9.2.0.jar ionic-js-sidemenu1      1
>   Error        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/9.2.0/firebase-core-9.2.0.pom    ionic-js-sidemenu1      1
>   Error        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/9.2.0/firebase-core-9.2.0.jar    ionic-js-sidemenu1      1
>   Error        file:/C:/Users/Hassan/.m2/repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/9.2.0/firebase-core-9.2.0.pom   ionic-js-sidemenu1      1
>   Error        file:/C:/Users/Hassan/.m2/repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/9.2.0/firebase-core-9.2.0.jar   ionic-js-sidemenu1      1
>   Error        Required by:   ionic-js-sidemenu1      1
>   Error        :android:unspecified   ionic-js-sidemenu1      1
>   Error        > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0. ionic-js-sidemenu1      1
>   Error        Searched in the following locations:   ionic-js-sidemenu1      1
>   Error        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/9.2.0/firebase-messaging-9.2.0.pom   ionic-js-sidemenu1      1
>   Error        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/9.2.0/firebase-messaging-9.2.0.jar   ionic-js-sidemenu1      1
>   Error        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/9.2.0/firebase-messaging-9.2.0.pom  ionic-js-sidemenu1      1
>   Error        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/9.2.0/firebase-messaging-9.2.0.jar  ionic-js-sidemenu1      1
>   Error        file:/C:/Users/Hassan/.m2/repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/9.2.0/firebase-messaging-9.2.0.pom ionic-js-sidemenu1      1
>   Error        file:/C:/Users/Hassan/.m2/repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/9.2.0/firebase-messaging-9.2.0.jar ionic-js-sidemenu1      1
>   Error        Required by:   ionic-js-sidemenu1      1
>   Error        :android:unspecified   ionic-js-sidemenu1      1
>   Error       * Try:  ionic-js-sidemenu1      1
>   Error       Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,""D:\My Work\Ionic\ionic-js-sidemenu1\ionic-js-sidemenu1\platforms\android\gradlew" cdvBuildDebug -b "D:\My Work\Ionic\ionic-js-sidemenu1\ionic-js-sidemenu1\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"   ionic-js-sidemenu1

All you need is to add this 3 plugin

```
⁠⁠⁠ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-velda-devicefeedback
```

Comment: did you get your google-services.json?

Comment: yes add into platform>android > directory

Comment: and you tried to build the apk into the phone, and send notification from the firebase console?

Comment: when i tried to build on phone, above error stop the build

Comment: @JCBorlagdan can you provide me some demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get this error now, this is not in your **FCM** or other **plugins**.

It's just your version of google play services.

Open your **Android SDK Manager** 
Update both **Google Play Services rev 30** and 
 **Google Repository** **rev 26**.

Try building again.

Comment: did you have any sample project just for tutorial

Comment: i don't have any. sorry, but i'm pretty much sure that it's all about your version of Google play services and repository

Comment: now build and deploy perfectly.. but can't received any notification

Comment: close the app, make sure it's not running in the background and try sending notification again

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets 285 
Error  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. poush  1 
Error  Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'. poush  1 
Error  Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,""D:\My Work\Ionic\poush\poush\platforms\android\gradlew" cdvBuildDebug -b "D:\My Work\Ionic\poush\poush\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true" poush  1