# Get Device Tocken in ionic using FCM

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send notification in ionic app using FCM but first I want to get device token using FCM. I have already tried below method to get device token.working. But I want to get device token using FCM. Anyone knows how to get, kindly help.

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    var push = new Ionic.Push({
      "debug": true
    });

    push.register(function(token) {
      console.log("My Device token:",token.token);
      push.saveToken(token);  // persist the token in the Ionic Platform
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: hmm you're probably looking at very old documents. check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37653251/firebase-cloud-messaging-with-ionic-app/39262282#39262282

this if you wanna send push notification to all the device who downloaded the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this plugin : https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm
you can access your Device token this way :

```
FCMPlugin.getToken(
  function(token){
    alert(token);
  },
  function(err){
    console.log('error retrieving token: ' + err);
  }
);
```

Everything needed to use Firebase is in this plugin.

Have fun :)

Comment: Wherever you want to get your token, for example, just over your push.register function !

Comment: i have paste this code onclick function... but i give that error.FCMPlugin is not defined
    at Scope.$scope.click (http://localhost:8100/js/app.js:34:1)
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> . how to solve kindly help

Comment: Did you install the plugin ?

Comment: @umersafeer did you find any solution chat notification in ionic

Comment: what if i have login page ? I mean we get the token in `appp.js` but required same token after user login then ? any suggestions