# Ionic 1 FCM Push Notifications With Images

Tags: ionic-framework

I am working on ionic1 project. I need to display the push notifications with images in it for the Android platform. I am able to display the notifications with the text but images are not appearing somehow. I need some working solution for displaying image after the text in ionic1 in the notification bar.

I am using https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm

Comment: I used this SO question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37653251/firebase-cloud-messaging-with-ionic-app to solve this exact problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Cloud Messaging with Ionic app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37653251/firebase-cloud-messaging-with-ionic-app)

Comment: I have seen the example but the notifications are already working in my case, I only need to display the images in the notification bar

Comment: update the code sample for better understand