# Firebase registration token not generate android

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to integrate Firebase Push Notification in my app so I set below code for that. I integrated the following code for notification:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

When I run it with my credentials and API key I am getting Firebase reg id blank every time. Any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: it is hard to replicate in that way.. show your logs.

Comment: @sourabhbans ;My logcat get error mesage like  Firebase reg id: null

Comment: refer this link https://paramandroidguru.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this link: 
[Firebase (FCM) how to get token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787373/firebase-fcm-how-to-get-token)

I solved it by referring the answer by activesince93. His answer stated that

> New Firebase token is generated (onTokenRefresh() is called) when:
>
> 1. The app deletes Instance ID
> 2. The app is restored on a new device
> 3. The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
> 4. The user clears app data.

I believe his answer is from this doc by google: 
[Access the device registration token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register)

I can get the Firebase reg id after I uninstall and reinstall my app. Hope it helps.