# Android Firebase services like Messaging, Deeplink not working on build versions

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-deep-link

This sounds ridiculous but I am banging my head for the past 2 days. Deeplink and FirebaseMessagingService are working absolutely perfect when I run the app through Android Studio. Neither deep link nor onNewToken() method is not called when I install the app manually by building the app through Generate APks. Really, I have no idea about this strange issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have only saved debug SHA1 key on Firebase.
You also have to save your release SHA1 key on Firebase. Here is [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup) how to create the release SHA1 key

Comment: In spite of release sha1 key in firebase console, FirebaseMessagingService's onNewToken() should be called on the first launch

Comment: The onNewToken method will only be called when a new token is generated.

Comment: to get Token you have to do some thing like this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41515597/10695093

Comment: Yes, but the real problem is it is not called in the release build deep-linking also not working but everything is working when I install through Android Studio with the USB cable.

Comment: how u have generated your release sha1 key

Comment: I have added SHA1 & SHA256 both keys in the firebase console

Comment: you have to upload only sha1 key I am just saying how you have generated release sha1 key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189105/discussion-between-jaya-prakash-and-akash-suresh-dandwate).

Comment: this way you can generate the keys see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/15727931/10695093

Comment: It is working now, after adding SHA1 fingerprint, I have to clean the project