# Get fcm token programmatically

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have initialised firebase in android without using the google-services plugin like this

```
FirebaseOptions.Builder builder = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                        .setApplicationId("application-id")
                        .setApiKey("api-key")
                        .setDatabaseUrl("database-url")
                        .setStorageBucket("storage-bucket")
                        .setProjectId("project-id")
                        .setGcmSenderId("gcm-sender-id");
                FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context,builder.build());
```

Now after initialising the firebase app how can i get the token generated to send push notification via FCM

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787373/firebase-fcm-how-to-get-token, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51123197/firebaseinstanceidservice-is-deprecated and https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#retrieve-the-current-registration-token

Answer (score 2):

I think you could get it like:

```
 FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(instanceIdResult -> {
            String token = instanceIdResult.getToken();
            updateToken(token, apiService, sessionManager); // update token on server
        });
```