# Is it possible ,without app server to send push notification using fire-base?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible ,without app server to send push notification using fire-base real time database and notifications in android?

Comment: yes, see my post  [Send Push Notifications from 1 android phone to another with out server](https://androidredman.wordpress.com/2017/08/27/send-push-notifications-from-1-android-phone-to-another-with-out-server/)

Answer (score 0):

As [Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen) comments here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37376757/3853450, I think it is possible :)

Comment: Avoid giving answers like "seems" , "i think". Give the correct answer else comment on the question.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I edit it! Thanks! :)