# FCM - Send to all users/devices from a PHP script

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to send (broadcast) a Firebase Notification from a script to all users without requiring access tokens? From within the Firebase console, no access token is required, so I was wondering if this functionality is available when sending a data notification from a PHP script.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371990/how-can-i-send-a-firebase-cloud-messaging-notification-without-use-the-firebase), but all the answers required to set the `to` or the `registration_ids` JSON field. Like so:

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization:key=<Your Api key>"  -X POST -d '{ "data": { "score": "5x1","time": "15:10"},"to" : "<registration token>"}' https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

I would prefer not to handle the collection of all access tokens and send a notification to everyone using the app automatically.