# How to send FCM notification to all android devices using Node.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I want to send the notification to my Android app developed using Ionic t from Node.Js code. I have tried following code and getting `Exactly one of topic, token or condition is required.`

How can I send notification all my users without any condition?

```
var serviceAccount = require("/path/to/config.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://myApp.firebaseio.com"
});

var message = {
    notification: {
      title: '$GOOG up 1.43% on the day',
      body: '$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.'
    }
  };


admin.messaging().send(message).then(res=>{
    console.log("Success",res)
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log("Error:",err)
})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to send a notification to all users, then the best thing is to register the users to a certain topic, example `food` then everyone registered to that topic will receive a notification.

In your code above, you are getting that error because you did not provide to whom you want to send the notification.

If token:

```
var registrationToken = 'YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN'; <-- token of user
var message = {
notification: {
  title: '$GOOG up 1.43% on the day',
  body: '$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.'
  }
token: registrationToken
};
```

If topic:

```
var topic = 'food';
var message = {
notification: {
  title: '$GOOG up 1.43% on the day',
  body: '$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.'
  }
  topic: topic
};
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages

Comment: There is no way to specify the package like how I can send all users in Firebase notification console?

Comment: do you want to send from the console?

Comment: Nope. I want to send through Node.JS code.
But I want to mention the package name like `com.a.b` like we specify in the console and all users who have app will get notified.

Comment: ahh this is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40052813/android-push-notifcation-toward-an-specified-application-package (only way is through topics)