# How we can send image and icon by using Firebase cloud messaging(fcm) for push notification in android

Tags: php, android, ionic-framework, notifications

I want to send an image and icon in my Push notification from my Serverside(php) to my app.
[image: image of cat]

I have searched on Google but was unable to get the proper result.
I get [FCM PHP Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39058440/2143446). I use these code for sending notification but when I use "image and icon" parameter image not receive in notification.

In GCM it's easy to send icon and image in Push notification

```
 $fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
    'data' => array(
        "title" => "SamplePush Application",
        "style" => "inbox"; //picture/inbox,
        "message" => "I am just testing Push notification",
        "notId" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "summaryText" => "Venha provar os nossos Gins",
        "image" => "http://gintonico.com/content/uploads/2015/03/fontenova.jpg",
        "picture" => "http://media5.letsbonus.com/products/285000/285006/14014409744462-0-1700x690.jpg"
    ) ,
```

If anyone can send image and icon in notification using FCM please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, I change my plugin and use [phonegap-plugin-push v2.0.x](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/tree/v2.0.x) and it work fine. Now I am able to send big image in the notification.

[image]

Comment: can this be achieved using "cordova-plugin-fcm"...?

Answer (score 0):

Notification image must be PNG image. Replace jpg image with png image.