# Where can I see and manage topics in FCM

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Do you know where I can see and manage topics (a sort or admin console) in FCM?

Thanks!

*** UPDATE ***
Using the FCM cordova plugin (FCMPlugin), I wrote the following in my app:

```
FCMPlugin.getToken(function(token){
      console.log('FCMPLUGIN: ', token);
      alert(token); // the token pops up in my app
    });

FCMPlugin.subscribeToTopic('topics/chats/' + currentUser.auth.uid);
```

No error, everything seems to work fine but when I go to my notifications console, I cannot see my topic:
[image]

I read in some doc that sending a message to a topic that doesn't exists creates it so I tried through the test console of FCMPlugin (https://cordova-plugin-fcm.appspot.com/) but still no topic in my console... any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 11):

You can see all active topics in the Firebase console by going to the [Notifications panel](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/notification). You can send notification messages to those topics from there too.

Steps (since some folks have a hard time finding it):

1. Navigate to the [notification composer](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/-/notification/compose)
2. Enter a <kbd>Notification text</kbd> for the message
3. Click <kbd>Next</kbd>
4. In the <kbd>Target</kbd> click <kbd>Topic</kbd>
5. Click inside the <kbd>Message topic</kbd> box to see the list of topics

There is not really much you can manage about topics aside from that. Topics are automatically created when a user subscribes to them or when you send a message to them through the FCM API.

Comment: I have been looking around in this panel before writing my questions but the only things I could see is the default topics I guess (all and ios) though I subscribed a user to a custom topic from my app... so I don't really understand what I am doing wrong and why I am not seeing my custom topics.

Comment: Topics may take a few hours to show up. But aside from that, it should be automatic once a user subscribes to a topic in your project. So if the topics don't show up, I suspect the user might not be subscribed. Do you receive messages that you send to the topic (for example [using curl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371990/how-can-i-send-a-firebase-cloud-messaging-notification-without-use-the-firebase/37376757#37376757))?

Comment: I switched to OneSignal... :)

Comment: It only shows statistic such as how many msg sent, received, opened, etc.; I couldn't find info related to topics here. Perhaps the feature has been moved elsewhere?

Comment: I found the list in the composer page that Manuel RODRIGUEZ has shared in original question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen telling lie in this answer. There's not any topic info available at Firebase Notification panel, which is asked in original question.

Comment: Really Pooja, it's still there for me. I added detailed steps on how I can see the topics in my projects.

Comment: @Pooja I was having trouble locating where in the UI I could target by topic also, but below Target (Step 2 in the current Firebase Notification Compose UI) there is a tab control that defaults to User segment. I nearly missed it but, there is a tab labeled Topic to the right of the User segment tab. It took me longer than it should have to find it, hope this helps others!

Comment: That's step 4 in my edit. Sorry if this wasn't immediately clear.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes we can send notification to target topic but if you look in original question, user wants to manage topics or he/she wants to see list of topics.

Comment: Step 5: "Click inside the `Message topic` box to **see the list of topics**"

Comment: @Pooja is right. Frank's answer is not enough. There is no extra panel on the Firebase website to manage the topics. You can only see the topic list where Frank wrote. I have two useful links for those interested in how to manage topics on the backend. [listing topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66098779/firestore-architecture-for-subscription-topic) and    [managing topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-topics)