# Firestore architecture for subscription topic

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I would like to create an architecture for a Firestore based Android application where you can "subscribe" to different topics to follow. Let's say that you want to subscribe to 3 different topics and then have a common listview where only stuff published from those three topics are shown. How would I go to create such an architecture (not a question about coding here really, only how I would structure the architecture of such a thing using Firestore).

Any tips, help, links etc. Are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a complicated thing to provide a Firestore structure from scratch as I am sure what you described are not all of the requirements that your app has. That being said I will share how I would do it based on the problem you proposed:

Basically I would create 2 collections:

```
Topics Collection
    uid
    field1
    ...
    fieldN
    userIds[]

Publications Collection
    uid
    field1
    ...
    fieldN
    topicIds[]
```

And how would it work is, anytime a user subscribe to a topic, you add his `uid` to the `userIds` array, once you want to check to which topics the current user is subscribed you can just query if his id is in said array.

As per publications, the same logic applies, if you want the user to get the publications from the topics he is subscribed to you can just use the result of the query mentioned above and do the following query for each of its results:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser
var listPubs = [];
db.collection("topics")
  .where("userIds", "array-contains", user.uid)
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) =>{
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          db.collection("publications")
            .where("topicIds", "array-contains", doc.id)
            .get()
            .then((secondSnapshot) =>{
                listPubs.concat(secondSnapshot.docs);
            })
      });
  })
```

**NOTE**: This is not at all optimized but should be a good starting point for you to consider your structure. Also, I have not added a user collection as you can use the data from Firebase auth but you could create one if needed.

Comment: Just a question. Since the limited document size is 1MB if I'm not mistaken; is there a work-around if topics ID's goes above that? Let's assume you can have like 20 000 uids on each topic with the 1MB limitation. What if that exceeds to 30k?