# Android Firebase Notification .

Tags: android, firebase, notifications

Hello Folks currently I'm working on an app in which I need to integrate notification in my app , but I am new to this and I didn't understand anything from google firebase notification management system, so can anyone explain me in short and simple way.

Comment: documentation and example. Very informative and step by step : https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging

Comment: Hello Mr. @Dexter I have gone through it several times but didn't understand anything.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Notification is former GCM.

In brief, where there is a device, It has its own ID. The Id is send to somewhere to your server. Like here

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/OlM0gCs2tbU

Then, save the ID (token) into your server database.

Then, when you want to send some notification use this code like here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37376757/1979882

to catch notification

use this sample

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37376757/1979882

Answer (score 1):

The steps to be followed are -
1) Create a firebase project
2) Implement it into your android app by copying the google-services.json file.
3) Create a firebase instance ID service which generates a new token when the app is installed.
4) Create a firebase messaging event service which receives the notification from FCM and displays it in a notification builder. 
For further information - 
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-cloud-messaging-tutorial-android/