# Android - Firebase cloud message push notification daily and base on location

Tags: android, rest, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to Android Development. I am coding one app that using Firebase Cloud Messaging to push notification. I already read document at Firebase Console. But i got a problem. Is there any solution to push notification daily at specific time and the content of message changing based on user device location such as Hello in England, Bonjour in France, Hallo in Germany. Thank you.

Comment: First you need to put up a webserver which saves all the devices details(firebase token too), after that for sending push on specific time you have to write a webscript (may be using cron job), 
For sending location based content again you need to make provision on app side to send location periodically to the webserver again using webscript.

Answer (score 0):

You should make and script to do that .
Please go through the link where you can find the necessary script to do that.
you can also send notification to your app via google firebase console.
but you want to send custom message as per the country so you have to make the script with little amendment.
[Links to send FCM firebase notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371990/how-can-i-send-a-firebase-cloud-messaging-notification-without-use-the-firebase)