# How to send game request push notification for user logged in with Facebook?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have a quiz game and I log in using Facebook SDK. 
In this way, I can see all my friends that play game and invite them for a match.

My question is: how to invite specific friend and send push notification to him?
I have list of friends with their Fb ids, and when I click on one, I want to send push notification, so friend could click on it and compete with me.

I have read a lot on internet, but did not find anything useful.
I don't want to write server code. Node or something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Game requests offer a "to" parameter for specifying a specific friend ID, that is all you need:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/gamerequests

As you can read in the docs, it can be a list of IDs and/or invite tokens (if the user did not authorize your App yet).

For push notifications in your App, you can take a look at Firebase, for example: [How can I send a Firebase Cloud Messaging notification without use the Firebase Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371990/how-can-i-send-a-firebase-cloud-messaging-notification-without-use-the-firebase)

Comment: In this way, I get notification in facebook. But I want to receive it as normal push notification in Android, so user could click on it and compete.

Comment: if you want to send push notifications from your android app...well, that is not really related to facebook.

Comment: added more information about push notifications. there is another thread about that already on stackoverflow