# Firebase Messaging from Node Admin for iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am trying to send push notification from firebase to iOS device but not successful. Following is the payload I tried:

```
var message = {
  notification: {
    title: '$GOOG up 1.43% on the day',
    body: '$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.',
  },
  apns: {
    headers: {
      "apns-priority": '10'
    },
    payload: {
      aps: {
        alert: {
          title: '$GOOG up 1.43% on the day',
          body: '$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.',
        },
        "content-available": true
      }
    }
  },
  token: "adacxxxxxx 152 string"
};
```

When I try to trigger `fbAdmin.messaging().send(message)`, I receive `{"code":"messaging/internal-error","message":"Internal error encountered."}`.

I have another format for Android and it was working fine. So, I am trying to understand why iOS is not working. Any suggestions or help is appreciated as I have spent a few days on this.

Comment: which library u r using?

Comment: I am using `"firebase-admin": "^6.1.0",` in Nodejs

Comment: @DevsiOdedra when I tried to send the notification from fcm API, I get the raw error message: "InvalidAPNsCredentials" and managed to solved it by correcting the configurations in firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to make this working myself by trying following.

[How can I send a Firebase Cloud Messaging notification without use the Firebase Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371990/how-can-i-send-a-firebase-cloud-messaging-notification-without-use-the-firebase)

After I tried to call fcm api, I get the error "InvalidAPNsCredentials". Then I realized my APN Auth Key is something wrong. Then, I had to redownload the APN auth key, corrected the Team ID and run the app again and now it is working!