# Send Push Notifications Programmatically Javascript

Tags: push-notification, aws-pinpoint

I have an Angular 2+ app where I have an interface to send Push Notifications to users of an Ionic App. 
What I want to do is to use the Web interface to send programmatically notifications with Javascript. Has anyone done this before?
Can anybody tell me how to do this? I would be really happy to see some code examples but a recommendation where to start and which API/SDK to use would be enough. 
I really do not want anyone to do this for me but some direction would really help me as I am new to Push Notifications from the Web.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) to work with push notifications. There is [a tutorial](http://tphangout.com/ionic-2-push-notifications/) to implement it to you Ionic App. But to send push notification you will need to have a server backend.

Comment: Can you show me some instructions on how to setup the server backend?

Comment: I had give more explication in my answer in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55263816/how-i-can-send-notifications-when-my-app-is-closed-in-ionic/55266110#55266110