# Send Push Notifications to Ionic3 from Web

Tags: web, push-notification, ionic3

I have build an Angular 2+ Web app, and an Android mobile app with Ionic 3.
What I want to do is to send Push Notifications from Web to the mobile app.
On the web I have an interface with the Title and Message of the notification to be send.
What I would like to ask is how it is possible to send notifications from web and receive it on the mobile device.
Can anyone show me any tutorial ideally with Firebase to do that?

Thank you

Comment: Repost : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55263816/how-i-can-send-notifications-when-my-app-is-closed-in-ionic/55266110#55266110

Answer (score 0):

you can use Push Notifications see docs on ionic website [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/push/)

and this is a tutorial  [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOOjamH1bAA)