# With react-native-firebase v6, app crashed when receive notification while in foreground

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I try to get `react-native-firebase` v6 to work in my app. I use React Native 0.59.10.

I have installed `react-native-firebase` v6 according to the [documentation](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/messaging/android). It didn't specify about adding service `MyFirebaseMessagingService` into the `AndroidManifest.xml` unlike in v5 so I didn't do it. Afterwards, the app didn't receive any notification while in foreground but did receive them while in background.

I tried to add `MyFirebaseMessagingService` into `AndroidManifest.xml` like so:

```xml
<service
    android:name=".java.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

There was some sort of a progress. The app crashed immediately after I sent a notification from Firebase console. Hence, I knew the app was aware of incoming notification but somehow crashed.

Below is my code to import and initialize a listener.

```js
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';

// Initialize notifications
const init = () => {
    try {
        messaging().onMessage((message) => {
            Alert.alert('Received', JSON.stringify(message));
        });
    } catch (err) {
        Alert.alert('Error', err.message);
    }
};
```

In summary, I expect to receive a notification while the app is in foreground but nothing happens if I don't add `MyFirebaseMessagingService` to `AndroidManifest.xml`. If I add it, the app will crash on receiving notification.

Comment: post a stacktrace.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya I already found the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Dorklord can you please help me with showing local notification in v6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay. After further hair pulling and research, I found out that this was en expected behaviour rather than a bug.

Adding `MyFirebaseMessagingService` or any other service to `AndroidManifest.xml` to install `react-native-firebase` v6 is unneccessary.

> Afterwards, the app didn't receive any notification while in foreground but did receive them while in background.

Actually, it does. After peeking through Android log with `adb logcat -s RNFirebaseMsgService:V`, I found out that `react-native-firebase` v6 doesn't support notification as of now. This is their code which made me think my app didn't receive any notification while in foreground.

```js
if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null && remoteMessage.getData().size() == 0) {
    // TODO broadcast intent when notifications module ready
    return;
}
```

It's still a to-do item for them lmao!!

It turned out I need to send a notification with custom data because it already is supported. Hence, I need to use it every time so my app could display anything upon receiving such a notification.

Comment: Dude, I had been struggling with same issue for 2 days before I found your answer. You are a godsend for me, thank you very much!

If someone want to test "data type" message delivering you could use curl/postman to send requests:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37376757/3175823

Comment: @fotonmoton glad I could help. Rock on!!