# Can't handle tap when app is in background

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

From Google documentation:

> Handle notification messages in a backgrounded app

> When your app is in the background, Android directs notification messages to the system tray. A user tap on the notification opens the app launcher by default.

But I need to handle tap and forward to my specific activity on my app (when app  in background).

```
class CustomFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {


    /*-
        Call this method only when app is foreground.
     
    */
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {
```

Method  onMessageReceived called only when app is in foreground.

Comment: Where is your code ? What you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Cloud Messages supports two [types of messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages): notification messages and data messages.

Notification messages get handled by the OS when your app is backgrounded. There is nothing you can change about that.

What you **can** do is send a data message, which is delivered to your application's `onMessage` handler no matter whether the app is active or not. Since this `onMessage` can be called even when the app is not active, it is in a `FirebaseMessagingService` class and not in an Activity.

Also see the Firebase documentation on [handling messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages) on Android.

Comment: Is it possible to send data message from Firebase console?

Comment: No. The Firebase console can only send Notification messages. But it's quite easy to do in code or from a command line: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371990/how-can-i-send-a-firebase-cloud-messaging-notification-without-use-the-firebase (the sample there sends a notification, but you can change the data)