# How to test FCM push notification to a device via a token ID

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/first-message), I need to do the following:

...

- Open the Notifications composer and select New notification.
- Enter the message text.
- Select Send test message.
- In the field labeled Add an FCM registration token, enter the registration token you obtained in a previous section of this guide.
- Click Test

But when I compose a notification, the pop-up looks like this and there is nowhere to add the token ID of the device; not to mention that there is no "Test" button. Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: I also can't immediately find a way to enter a token in the console anymore. You might want to try sending from a terminall with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371990/how-can-i-send-a-firebase-cloud-messaging-notification-without-use-the-firebase/37376757#37376757

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen its hiding took me a while to realise its there. When creating the campaign there will be a Test button on top right. Clicking that gives the option to specify the device token.

Answer (score 2):

The pop-up you shared appears when you click on the "**Review**" button at the bottom of the page. You can find the "**Send test message**" button on the right side of the page under "**Device preview**" section. After you click on "**Send test message**", a pop-up will be shown where you can add an FCM registration token and click on the "**Test**" button.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I had a hard time finding that too, I always tested using Publish till i decided to click that Test button one time then i saw the token field.

Comment: I hate the design of this field. It doesn't look like a text input!
Firebase need to fix this UI