# Disable automatic display of notification by firebase

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would just like to receive the notification data via the OnMessageReceived method and then display a custom notification with Unity's MobileNotification or UTNotification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any information in the `notification` property of a message is automatically handled by the system when the app is not active. If you don't want the system to automatically display a notification, make sure that your message contains no `notification` property. Data only messages are not displayed by the system automatically.

For more on this, also see the Firebase documentation on [message types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages).

---

While it *is* possible to add `data` properties to an FCM message that is sent through the Firebase console in the <kbd>Custom data</kbd> section of the <kbd>Additional options</kbd>, there is no way to send a data **only** message. Messages sent through the Firebase console will always have a `notification` property, which is what triggers the system to display them.

If you want to send data-only messages, the simplest way is through a CURL command as shown here: [How can I send a Firebase Cloud Messaging notification without use the Firebase Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371990/how-can-i-send-a-firebase-cloud-messaging-notification-without-use-the-firebase)

Comment: In this case I'm using the playfab cloud script to send the notification, and when I receive the data, firebase already sends the notification. If I didn't want this behavior I would have to follow this idea from CURL or even pubSub from playfab, I believe I understand.

Comment: I missed that you weren't necessarily asking about the Firebase console. I added an intro paragraph to my answer abuot message types.

Answer (score 0):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=fr#notifications_and_data_messages

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "data":{
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "body" : "great match!",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
}
```

***dont put key notification in your body request***

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "body":"great match!"
    },
    "data" : {
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
}
```