# How to upload APNs key, team id, key id on firebase through cloud console service account json using google cloud php client library?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I am currently using the Cloud Console to manage some of my services, and I perform all activities through the APIs provided by the console. I am using a Cloud Console service account JSON for authentication. Additionally, I am using the Google PHP Client library (https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) to access the APIs.
However, I am facing some challenges with finding the appropriate APIs to upload my Apple push notification files, team ID, and key ID for Apple notification configuration on Firebase. Could you please provide me with guidance on how I can accomplish this task programmatically?
Thank you for your assistance.

I am not able to upload my APNs file on firebase programmatically.

Comment: As per this document [google cloud-messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging) is deprecated. You may have a look these links: [link1](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cloud-messaging.html) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371990/)

Comment: Hii @RoopaM thanks for your response, but we are searching a rest api which can upload my APNs, team id and key id assets on firebase automatically. currently we are doing this task manually.