# How to send Firebase Push notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1) in a react-native applications?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase, react-native-fcm

The objective is to send push notifications using firebase cloud messaging to a react-native application , if possible using a common package, and the latest Firebase Cloud Messaging API, not the legacy API.

I have been trying to send push notifications using firebase cloud messaging Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1), which was implemented recently and  [react-native-firebase/messaging](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage). But I couldn't find any network requests made. I have followed the steps given in the documentation, but it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something here?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvIeS.png)

Comment: Sending a message **to** other devices to show a notification can only be done from a trusted environment, such as the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/notification/compose), [your development machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37376757), a [server that you control](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens), or something like [Cloud Functions/Cloud Run](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message).