# Add Action To Firebase Notification

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to add an action button to notifications produced on firebase 9.0.0, for Android, when app is in **background**.

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in order to customize notifications when app is on background, as Diego mentioned, the only current way is to create the notification yourself. Adding "data" key to notification payload, results in `onMessageReceived()` callback, on which you can create any notification andy notify.

Thing is, I tried to send a notification from Firebase console, rather then from the API. There I couldn't add the data key properly and catch it. From API all works fine.

Comment: Can you more specific on that **adding data key** or **only data key** in notification payload?

Answer (score 8):

firebase-cloud-messaging doesn't provide an API to add action buttons to the notifications.

You can request new features to the firebase library here:
https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

For now what you can do is to send a `data-message` with a custom payload via the [server-side API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream)
You can then receive that payload in onMessageReceived() and generate your custom notification.

Comment: Thank you! my issue was that I tried to send the notification from Firebase console. adding "data" key didn't work for me that way...

Answer (score 0):

I would consider reviewing the following documentation:

Handle messages in a backgrounded app

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream#backgrounded

This looks like you would need to change the intent filter for your FirebaseMessagingService to handle the OnClick action.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Alexander! I'm trying to customize the notification itself, and add an action to it. However, click_action defines what should happen when clicking on the entire notification.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already know that you have to use **only data key** ([I answered here, too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358462/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-in-background/39556690#39556690)) to send to your application in the background, you can add an action to notification message builder like this:

```
final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
.addAction(
                    R.drawable.ic_setting_light,
                    res.getString(**R.string.Your_Button_String**),
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(
                            context,
                            0,
                            **Your_Intent_To_Open_When_Button_Is_Click**,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

Of course this has to be inside handling logic from Android side.

Note: Notification actions are supported only in Android 4.1 or later.