# Android app is not receiving FCM notification when closed

Tags: android, notifications, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am checking [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) to send notification. Have implemented it already and its receiving notification when app is in open state. But if I close app, its no longer gives notification. Is there any solution for this.

Code:

```
WebRequest wRequest;
wRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
wRequest.Method = "post";
wRequest.ContentType = " application/json;charset=UTF-8";
wRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", AppId));

wRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SenderId));

string postData = "{\"registration_ids\":[\"" + regIds + "\"], \"data\": "+ value +"}";

Byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
wRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

Stream stream = wRequest.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
stream.Close();

WebResponse wResponse = wRequest.GetResponse();
```

Messaging service-

```
public class MessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Map<String, String>  data = remoteMessage.getData();
        sendNotification(data);
    }

    public void showMessage(Map<String, String>  serverData) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(serverData.get("Title"))
                .setContentText(serverData.get("Message"))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        manager.notify(Integer.parseInt(serverData.get("ItemId")),builder.build());
    }

    private void sendNotification(Map<String, String>  serverData) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0 /* request code */, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        long[] pattern = {500,500,500,500,500};

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
                .setContentTitle(serverData.get("Title"))
                .setContentText(serverData.get("Message"))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVibrate(pattern)
                .setLights(Color.BLUE,1,1)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(serverData.get("ItemId")), notificationBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

Main activity-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("test");
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    }
}
```

Manifest-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="test.com.firebasenotify">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".MessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".InstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Show fcm listener class, and show the POST request you make to fcm

Comment: Updated messaging service, FCM post and main activity code

Comment: Do you receive the message in the onreceive at least?

Comment: yes I receive message on onMessageReceived when my app is open or at least running in the background and also get notification. If I close the app its not working. I should get notification if the app is closed too

Comment: Can u add the manifest as well

Comment: updated manifest also

Comment: Ok looks good. What do you mean if you say to "close" the app? Force stop?

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge on mobile terminology. What I mean is if I restart my phone then all application will be closed. e.g. even if I have not opened facebook app, I will still get notification from facebook app

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. After I restart my phone I still receive messages of my app even if I don't open the app

Comment: even if I clear all app without restarting. It does not work for me. I need to keep it open or run in the background. I am using android version 4.4.4

Comment: Is there any setting I am missing in firebase console

Comment: When the app is not running (or backgrounded), `onMessageReceived` will not be called for notifications. In such a situation Android should show a system notification (in the bar at the top) when the notification comes in.

Comment: If I kill app, no notification is displaying. Sot sure what is the issue

Comment: I am initialized FCM in MainActivity - onCreate. Logically thinking this method will get called once I open the APP.  Is this the issue - when app is closed its not working?  Is there any way I can call FCM initialization when app is installed or something like that.

Comment: You don't have to initialize FCM, since you're not using the topics

Comment: @Frank it will be called if there is no `notification` key in the POST payload

Comment: Can you please explain it little more. I am not able to make it work still if app is closed

Comment: @TimCastelijns correct, that's why I said "for notifications" ;-)

Comment: @Frank ah. My bad. Sometimes my eyes skip a couple of words..

Comment: @AnupDasGupta i also facing same problem, but it is occur only when i lock my cell phone more than 5 to 10 min, then i doesn't get any notifications, but when i unlock it i instantly get those notifications no matter app is open or not.
Did you find out why these problem arises in FCM ?

Comment: Did anyone get a fix for this issue? In my case, this issue is occurring in all devices having Android 5.1. Not happening in devices 7.0 above. Donno about 6 though.
If the app is background then notification received, if it's closed completely then receives nothing.

Answer (score 10):

There was no issue with the code. I was using Mi note 4, and somehow it does not show notification in Mi4 when app is closed. I tested with other android device and its working fine.

Thanks to Tim Castelijns and Frank van Puffelen for participating in the conversation.

Comment: For MI you need to put app in auto-start mode in Security to get notification when app is closed

Comment: Thanks man, in redmi prime2 also getting same problem. Did you find any solution for this problem in MI devices?

Comment: Vivo,opp also get the same problem any solution please give

Answer (score 2):

There's good solution and explanation about that issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40083727/13195188). You need to set high priority for notification to tell android react immediately, otherwise it takes couple of minutes to display received notification.

Answer (score 0):

I used **Legacy Server Key** instead of **Server Key** it had worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

adding **time_to_live** key in your POST Payload will solve this problem.The value of this parameter must be a duration from 0 to 2,419,200 seconds, and it corresponds to the maximum period of time for which FCM stores and attempts to deliver the message. **"time_to_live" : 3** [Refer Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)

Comment: This is probably valid only if the user comes back to the application.

Answer (score -3):

As per **FCM** docs **onMessageReceived()** won't be called when app is in the **background**. You should send a **notification** object on order to show it up in the system tray and when user clicks it the **launcher activity** will be open with data as **extras** with the **intent**. For payloads you should use **data** object. [see docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) and [Receive Messages in an Android App](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

Comment: if you see the code there no notification object. He is only sending data object

Comment: you need to send notification object as well.

Comment: but if we will send notification object then it will not hit onMessageReceived and notification will be handled by android itself and will be displayed in notification tray (without your client app). And if we send without notification object but data object is there then it will always hit onMessageReceived.