# LocalBroadcastManager is not called when app is killed. I want to update my UI when notification is received in background

Tags: android

I have used FCM to receive notification. When my app is killed, I receive the notification but my UI is not updated since onMessageReceived() in FCM is not called. How can I update my UI in activity?

Comment: take BroadcastReceiver & intent serivce, you can update UI in handler once that view is on Foreground

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358462/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-in-background/37471326#37471326