# FCM: I have used FCM to receive notification for my app. When my app is in foreground it groups all notifications but not when app is in background

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am able to group notifications for my app when it is in foreground. Whenever the app goes in background it creates multiple notification. How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase onMessageReceived not called when app in background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358462/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-in-background)

Answer (score 0):

As google says in this [site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience?hl=en), when app is in background notifications are administrated by the system by default :

> Notifications delivered when your app is in the background. In this
>   case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray. A
>   user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.

But if you want to work with the notifications by "yourself" you should send the 'data message' instead of the 'notification' as is said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37471326/3812081) and you can handle the notification.