# Android - Firebase Notification not opening targeted activity when app is in background but working properly in foreground

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have tried some solution from the stackoverflow . But not working properly in my case.
**Below is my `MyFirebaseMessagingService` class which extends `FirebaseMessagingService`**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService   extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    String url , title , body ;

    Map<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


        title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

        if(remoteMessage.getData().size()>0){
            Log.d("DATA", remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            try{
                data = remoteMessage.getData();
                url = data.get("url");
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("Error", e.toString());
            }

            showNotification(url , title , body);
        }






    }

    private void showNotification(String url, String title, String body) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationViewer.class);
        intent.putExtra("URL",url);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this) ;
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(body);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());

    }
}
```

Below is my `AndroidManifest.xml` code .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="dcastalia.com.munshijobsportal">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />


    <application
        android:name=".Controller.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <service android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity android:name=".activity.NotificationViewer"
            android:exported="true">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have tried out some solution but not working in my case. Everything is working fine when app is foreground but not working in background. **I want to open a particular activity name `NotificationViewer.Java` activity when user click on the notification. But when my app is in background it keep opening my  Launcher Activity.**

Comment: It's because when app is in background notifications are administrated by the system by default , FirebaseMessagingService is never called : look my answer here: (http://stackoverflow.com/a/42343510/3812081)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set click action in your json payload in notification request
 'click_action' => 'YourTAG' and apply same tag in your manifest activity

```
<activity
      android:name=".activity.NotificationViewer">
      <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="YourTAG" />  
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>              
      </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. Should bind this like below : `"data" : {
     "url" : "https://www.google.com",
     "name": "Piash",
            "click_action" : "tag"
   }`

Comment: you need to add tag inside notification object, e.g.: "click_action":"YourTAG" from server side

Comment: I edit my AndroidManifest.xml like below: 
`<activity android:name=".activity.NotificationViewer"
            android:exported="true"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="action_tag" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>`
And add 
 ` "data" : {
    "click_action": "action_tag"
   }` 
But still not working,

Comment: its not working becuase you are adding inside data obejct, you need to add inside notification object...<<"notification": {"title": "Click Action Message","text": "Sample message","click_action":"action_tag"}>>

Comment: thanks for your solution. I added it in notification object . Now it's working fine. Thanks

Comment: i have faced another problem , i am sending a url in my data object but this url is not get when i open notificatoin. my json format is below: 
 `"to": "/topics/news",
 "notification" : {
      "body" : "great match! ",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "click_action": "action_tag"
    },
 "data" : {
     "url" : "https://www.google.com",
     "name": "Piash"
  
   }
}`

Comment: you need to getvalue from your bundle.

Comment: So should i use Bundle instead of putExtra()  to pass my data from MyFirebaseMessagingService to NotificationView class.

Comment: no, on background it will automatically send in bungle, you need check bundle is null or not, if not then fetch your value from bundle.

Comment: thanks @Jd . I got the point . Every value is sent to notification as an key value of json .

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using the Firebase **Notification** message instead of the **Data** message.

If this is the case, using **Data** FCM message should do the trick for you.

As can be seen in https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

> Use notification messages when you want FCM to handle displaying a notification on your client app's behalf. Use data messages when you want to process the messages on your client app.

**Notification Messages**:

When your application is in the *foreground*, it receives the payload, but when in the *background*, Notification messages are delivered to the notification tray.

**Data Messages**:
These are are always delivered to the application, regardless if it is in the foreground or in the background.

*NOTE:* The FCM data message alone will not bring your application in the foreground. You will need additional code that will do that upon reception of the data message.