# Firebase notifications do not give Intent data to launcher OR onMessageReceived() when app is in background

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a problem with Firebase notifications.

When my app is completely closed and I send a notification, the app `launcher` gets the notification Data and can handle the incoming notification. Everything works fine then. But when I have the application open in the `background` (by exiting out via the home button) then neither my App `launcher` nor my `onMessageReceived()` method get called.

I can't find a reason why this would happen.

(`onMessageReceived()` is called correctly when app is in foreground)

**EDIT**: 
At the moment my onMessageReceived only logs if it got a message

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: Message from: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
}
```

**SOLUTION**:
I solved the problem by sending a `data notification` and then manually checking in the `onMessageReceived()` function if the app is in foreground and only displaying a notification then

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase onMessageReceived not called when app in background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358462/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-in-background)

Comment: Post your onMessageRecived() here for better help

Comment: Actually there are two types of message in firebase. for your query try to use "Data" message. see link [https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options]