# Firebase Notification not working in background

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need help. Firebase Notifications is Not Working in Background. This is My Code:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Log.d(TAG, "FROM:" + remoteMessage.getFrom());
   sharedPreference = getSharedPreferences(Global.SECURETRADE, 0);
    UID = sharedPreference.getString(Global.ID, "");


        Uri defaultSoundUri=RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)`enter code here`;

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new
                NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.small_secure_trade_app_icon);

        } else {

            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_secure_trade_app_icon);
        }

        notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.securetrade_icon));
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"));
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("body"));
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationBuilder.setSound(defaultSoundUri);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager)
                        getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

    }




}
```

Comment: How are you sending the message?

Comment: I am also wondering the same, before it was working properly

Comment: I am also wondering why it is not working, Firebase is given lots of errors, It was wokring perviously

Comment: Can u post your manifest

Comment: "onMessageReceived" will not get triggered when app is in background.You have to handle it like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37395785/3111083. Or try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43869272/3111083 (not tried it).

Comment: Try My solution?<br>
I've already tried it.<br>
And it works<br> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897883/how-to-handle-notifications-with-fcm-when-app-is-in-either-foreground-or-backgro/48899186#48899186

Answer (score 2):

when app is in background or killed you have to use data payload for notification.
[Firebase onMessageReceived not called when app in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358462/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-in-background?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove 'notification' section from the json you sent through push notification.
Simply sent the 'data' section, onMessageReceived will work as normal

Comment: nah, its only showing the notification in Tray,  Not displaying message

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Firebase will not call the onMessageReceived() when the app is in background unless you make the notification request body changes from yoour server code.

Checkout this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40083727/4620609

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending **data-messages** (not **notification-messages**) ?

**notification-messages** don't call `onMessageReceived()`

> Use notification messages when you want FCM to handle displaying a
>   notification on your client app's behalf. Use data messages when you
>   want to process the messages on your client app.

Read more here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

PS: FCM Web Console always sends notification-messages

---

If you are sending a **data-messages**, and `onMessageReceived()` is not called...
then it's a different problem.

It might even be a problem of that specific device.
See [Push notifications using FCM not received when app is killed android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44807973/push-notifications-using-fcm-not-received-when-app-is-killed-android/44872502#44872502)

Answer (score -1):

when app running in background onMessageReceive will not work

offline message coming to **launcher activity** just copy this peace of code in your launcher activity and check it. it will work.

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        Logger.info(TAG, "FIRE BASE OFF LINE NOTIFICATIONS COMING TO THIS BLOCK--->");

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        Set<String> keys = bundle.keySet();
        for (String key : keys) {
            Logger.info(TAG, "json object--->" + key + "---values--" + JSONObject.wrap(bundle.get(key)));
        }
    }
```

and your payload should be like this

```
{ "notification": {
    "title": "Your Title",
    "text": "Your Text",
     "click_action": "OPEN_ACTIVITY_1" // should match to your intent filter
  },
    "data": {
    "keyname": "any value " //you can get this data as extras in your activity and this data is optional
    },
  "to" : "to_id(firebase refreshedToken)"
}
```

[reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#messages-with-both-notification-and-data-payloads)