# Handling FCM notifications with notification payload, when the app is in background/killed?

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using AppCenter to send notifications for my Xamarin.Forms application. AppCenter is sending these notifications through Firebase-Cloud-Messaging service to Android devices. I need to handle incoming notifications without the user clicking the notification.

To handle incoming notifications when the app is in the background or killed, the notification payload should contain the `data` payload. But with AppCenter you can't send messages with 'data' payload (https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/87).

Now I'm looking for a way to handle notifications with a custom-service or something similar. In this SO question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47312925/5278005), someone has already mentioned that they already implemented it.

> @annihil we ended up having to create our own implementation of a BroadcastReceiver and JobIntentService to receive the FCM messages and explicitly pulling out the intent filters which sent the messages to the FCM classes shipped w/ their SDK – Jake Hall Jan 30 '18 at 11:58

How can we handle incoming notifications containing the **notification** payload when the app is in background/killed?

Comment: Could you please post the code you have tried and the specific problems you have encountered?