# How to handle case when app is resumed after push notification was received

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase messaging for push notifications in my Android app.
It's well known that `onMessageReceived` is not called when app is in background and the message includes 'body' and 'title'

This is an issue because, when app is resumed by user (simply bringing the app in foreground from task list), I can't figure out how to know that it's time for the app to refresh its data.

I could always have the app try to get data when comes into foreground, but ideally I wanted to rely on push notifications.

What is the best practice to refresh the data?

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect:

> It's well known that onMessageReceived is not called when app is in
>   background.

You can receive push notifications when your app is in background, even when your application is closed.

Comment: OK. Can you please share more information on how to do that? Based on what I read and the behavior I saw, when app is in background `onMessageReceived` is not being called. See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358462/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-in-background

Comment: it depends on the payload. You need 'data' key