# Firebase dynamic link, clear it after using once

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive

states that

> Calling getDynamicLink() retrieves the link and clears that data so
>   it is only processed once by your app.
>
> You normally call getDynamicLink() in the main activity as well as any
>   activities launched by intent filters that match the link.

I copied the following code from the doc.

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
        .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
        .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                Uri deepLink = null;
                if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                    deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                }


                // Handle the deep link. For example, open the linked
                // content, or apply promotional credit to the user's
                // account.
                // ...

                // ...
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
            }
        });
```

If I put the above code on `MainActivity:onCreate`

- when app is not running in background, deep link works fine
- when app is running in background, deep link is not recognized (the `onSuccess` callback doesn't get called)

If I put the above code on `MainActivity:onStart`

- when app is running in background or not, deep link works fine
- If user clicks deep link, main activity gets it and opens approapriate activity, (works fine) but when he tries to go back to the main activity, `onSuccess` callback fires again and he never be able to go to the main activity.

Comment: For the `onCreate()` case, you say `onSuccess()` does not get called.  Is `onFailure()` called instead?  In my use of `getDynamicLink()`, `onSuccess()` is always called, with the first call containing a `PendingDynamicLinkData` and subsequent calls containing null.

Comment: @BobSnyder no neither onSuccess nor onFailure doesn't get called.

Comment: I've got the same issue. I thought that getDynamicLink() clears data but it don't. And every call of this method return the same link every time. It can't be processed once so.

Comment: @eugene I am facing the same issue, did you solve this issue? Step 1: Received the dynamic link in the app. Step 2: Navigated to the required page. Step 3: App went to the background. Step 4: Opened the app from the background, the app still navigates to the previous dynamic link page. I am using onStart() method

Comment: I answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62985346/1432239

Comment: This solution worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61788281/1839500

Comment: When the App is in Background/Closed and notification contains notification data  `onMessageReceived` is never called. Check this topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/37395785/4024146 + this answer about data part: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40083727/4024146

Answer (score 5):

Duplicate the code written in `MainActivity:onCreate` method (entire Firebase Dynamic Links related code) inside `MainActivity:onNewIntent` method, this works irrespective of the app is running in the background or not.

Also `MainActivity:onNewIntent` method is not invoked if the app is not present in background hence no duplicate Firebase call happens.

Your **MainActivity** should look like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...

    FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
            .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                    // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                    Uri deepLink = null;
                    if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                        deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                    }


                    // Handle the deep link. For example, open the linked
                    // content, or apply promotional credit to the user's
                    // account.
                    // ...


            })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    //...

    FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
            .getDynamicLink(intent)
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                    // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                    Uri deepLink = null;
                    if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                        deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                    }


                    // Handle the deep link. For example, open the linked
                    // content, or apply promotional credit to the user's
                    // account.
                    // ...


            })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept a dirty hack by taking a global url and comparing it next time with new url , It's not perfect but it's the best I came up with .

```
 var previousDeepLink:String?=null //take it as global and static


    FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
    .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
            // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
            Uri deepLink = null;
            if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
            }

                 if(previousDeepLink==deepLink?.toString()){
                        return@OnSuccessListener
                    }
                    previousDeepLink=deepLink?.toString()



            // Handle the deep link. For example, open the linked
            // content, or apply promotional credit to the user's
            // account.
            // ...

            // ...
        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**The answer is in the [documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive):**

> **You must call getDynamicLink() in every activity** that might be
> launched by the link, even though the link might be available from the
> intent using getIntent().getData(). Calling getDynamicLink() retrieves
> the link and **clears that data so it is only processed once** by your
> app.
>
> You normally call getDynamicLink() in the main activity as well as any
> activities launched by intent filters that match the link.