# How to handle notification messages in a backgrounded app on Android 8?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I find the firebase doc about this subject too elusive: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#backgrounded

I've followed this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47392189/2068732and 
and I'm able to catch a notification received when the app is in background.

However, it is not satisfactory because the WakefulBroadcastReceiver class is deprecated.

What is the proper way to forward the notification to the MyFirebaseMessagingService's onMessageReceived() method ?

Here is my MyFirebaseMessagingService class:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Log.d(getClass().getName(), "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

            displayNotification(remoteMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

and manifest:

```
<service
    android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only if you have notification data in the payload `remoteMessage.getNotification() != null` will be true.
If you have data payload then `displayNotification()` should be outside the if block

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Log.d(getClass().getName(), "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
        displayNotification(remoteMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that already and that's not enough. When the app is in backgroud, the onMessageReceived() method of my FirebaseMessagingService subclass does not get called

Comment: You might have missed something in the manifest or somewhere, sharing code would be helpful. Both the class and manifest

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below permission.
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />` for more info you can check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html)

Comment: what is your min and max sdk version

Answer (score 0):

Please do check [this](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/push-notifications-with-firebase-cloud-messaging#module-backgroundcompatibility) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358462/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-in-background/40083727#40083727).

In short, you should modify your fcm payload by removing the `notification` body from it, leaving out the `data` payload only.

Well I'm not really not quite sure which one is better, but in my case by disabling `notification` body, gave me more control over my notification.