# Why onMessageReceived() method is not passing intent properly when the app is in background?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

Actually I'm trying to pass intent to an `activity` on click of the `push-notification` and it's working fine when the app is present in `foreground`.But when the app is in background although I'm receiving the `push-notification` without any problem but by clicking that notification I'm not getting intent in the `activity`. I tried to refer some questions in `SO` and tried adding flags like`PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`,
`PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT`,then in intent `(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP )` but none of them were helpful . Please help me to solve this issue it's been a pain in the neck from last two days.

**Manifest.XML:**

```
<activity android:name=".activities.ProfileHolder"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
       >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="profile" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**Notification Code in Node.js:**

```
var message = {
         to: u.fcm_token, 
         collapse_key: 'white', //anything can be given
         data: {
             type:"likes",
             post_owner_username:data.like_post_owner_username,
             owner_post_time:data.like_post_owner_time

         },
         priority: 'high',
         notification: {
             title: 'Infinity',
             body:notif_data,
             sound: "default",
             click_action: "profile",
             tag:"Hey Bro" //if specified then current msg would be  replaced by new msg
         }
     };

     fcm.send(message, function(err, response){
         if (err) {
             console.log(err);
         } else {
             console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", response);
         }
     });
```

**FirebaseMessagingService Class :**

```
/Varibales for notifications
String title, body, post_owner_username, post_owner_time, notif_commenter_username, notif_comment_time, follower_username,messager_username,type,action;
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    title=remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    body=remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    type=remoteMessage.getData().get("type");
    action=remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();

    Log.d("type",type);
    Log.d("type-2",title);

   if(type.equals("likes")){
       post_owner_username=remoteMessage.getData().get("post_owner_username");
       post_owner_time=remoteMessage.getData().get("owner_post_time");
   }
   else if(type.equals("comments")||type.equals("comment_likes")){
       post_owner_username=remoteMessage.getData().get("post_owner_username");
       post_owner_time=remoteMessage.getData().get("owner_post_time");
       notif_commenter_username=remoteMessage.getData().get("commenter_username");
       notif_comment_time=remoteMessage.getData().get("comment_time");
   }
   else if(type.equals("follow")){
       follower_username=remoteMessage.getData().get("follower_username");
   }
   else if(type.equals("messaging")){
       messager_username=remoteMessage.getData().get("sender_username");
   }

    //Showing Notification

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), Constants.CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_icon)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(body);

    Intent i = new Intent(action);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    if (type.equals("likes")) {
        b.putString("post_owner_username", post_owner_username);
        b.putString("post_owner_time", post_owner_time);
        b.putString("what", "show_notification_post");
        b.putString("Open","starred");

        // i.putExtra("Open", "starred");
    }
    else if (type.equals("comments")) {
        b.putString("post_owner_username",post_owner_username);
        b.putString("post_owner_time", post_owner_time);
        b.putString("notif_commenter_username", notif_commenter_username);
        b.putString("notif_comment_time",notif_comment_time);
        b.putString("what", "show_notification_post");
        b.putString("Open","starred");
        //i.putExtra("Open", "starred");
    }
    else if (type.equals("comment_likes")) {

        b.putString("post_owner_username", post_owner_username);
        b.putString("post_owner_time", post_owner_time);
        b.putString("notif_commenter_username", notif_commenter_username);
        b.putString("notif_comment_time", notif_comment_time);
        b.putString("what", "show_notification_post");
        b.putString("Open","starred");
        // i.putExtra("Open", "starred");
    }
    else if (type.equals("follow")||type.equals("follow_request")) {
        b.putString("searchUsername", follower_username);
        b.putString("Open","search_profile");
        //i.putExtra("Open", "search_profile");
    }
    else if(type.equals("messaging")){
        b.putString("Open","messaging");
        b.putString("msg_username",messager_username);
    }

    i.putExtras(b);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP );
    //ctx.startActivity(i);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    /*
     *  Setting the pending intent to notification builder
     * */

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    if (mNotifyMgr != null) {
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mNotifyMgr.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notificationID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);`

Comment: @ReazMurshed thanks for your time sir but your advise is not working in my case.

Comment: What device are you testing on?

Comment: @DavidWasser api 19 kitkat device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think the problem is because your are sending notification from fcm console !

From the docs

> "When your app is in the background on a user's device, notifications
>   are delivered to the system tray. When a user clicks on the
>   notification, the app launcher opens your app. If you want, you can
>   also add client message handling to receive notifications in your app
>   when it is already in the foreground on the user's device."

you should try sending notification with Fcm apis

**Hypothesis**
i think you should not send notification parameter when you are using api just send data parameter and parse the data in your onMessageReceived if you send notification it will delivered to system tray

[How to handle notification when app in background in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase)

Comment: See my case is satisfying all the tips given in your mentioned link . I'm sending **data** from server

Comment: @user8027365 try this :  in your nodejs code dont send notification just send data

Comment: You're an ingenius your hypothesis worked like a charm but could you please explain what's the issue with notification block

Comment: i'm no sure but i think there is two kind of message for fcm 1- display message and 2- data message and if you are adding notification to the your fcm push it consider that as display message and just shows message to user

Comment: Amir is correct! There are two types of messages, data and notification. The thing to keep in mind is when a notification message has a data payload, like in your original question, it is still treated as a notification message so is not sent to onMessageReceived when the app is in the background. If you send a data only message like Amir suggests then you will always get the onMessageReceived callback.