# Ionic Android App Not Receiving Phonegap Push Notifications

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have correctly configured Ionic App to install phonegap plugin push, and I have an application for which I am able to receive push notifications **only when the application is running in background** (e.g. by sending request through Postman while app is running in background), not when the application is active.

Any suggestions where should I look to check what is going wrong? Having googled for hours I am only **getting workarounds for the opposite case** i.e. notifications not being received when app is running in background.

I only need to know the possible locations and scenarios that can cause this particular type of problem. Any help would be appreciated. I tried running on physical device but without luck. Could there be any conflict with the versions of plugin with android, or possibilities of some properties or configuration to be changed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely that means you're sending a notification message, which is handled by the system when your app is inactive, and delivered to your app when it is active. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358462/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-in-background

Comment: That's not what I mean. I am actually getting the notifications when app is inactive. The weird part is when app is active then it does not receive any notification. Quite opposite of the case mentioned in the link. I will anyway check out the link to see if applies to my case as well.