# Firebase Cloud Messaging doesn't notify when application is running

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter

I want to know why Firebase Cloud Messaging doesn't send notifications when the app is running?

I started my application and tried to send a message. When I closed my application, it notified me. But when and I opened it and sent another notification, it didn't notify me, but it did trigger onMessage.

Is it possible to notify me when my application is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Messaging has two types of messages: notification messages and data messages.

Data messages are used for delivering data to your app. They are always delivered to your application's `onMessage` handler.

Notification messages are used to show a notification to the user. When your app is active, the messages are delivered to its `onMessage` handler, so that you can display the notification inside the app. But when the app is not active, notification messages are handled by the system and not delivered to your app's `onMessage` handler.

It sounds like you're sending a notification message. If you always want the message to be delivered to your applications `onMessage`, you should send a data message instead.

Also see:

- the [Firebase documentation on message types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)
- [Firebase onMessageReceived not called when app in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358462/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-in-background)