# FirebaseMessagingService doesn't work correct

Tags: android, push-notification

I have service implemented of FirebaseMessagingService. Today I noticed unusial behavior when phone blocked. I contunie to receive message and android show me via notification but code in onMessageReceived doesn't work.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    final Context context = this;

    if(remoteMessage == null){
        return;
    }

    if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null){
        try {
            final  Message msg = createMessage(remoteMessage.getNotification());
            Handler handler= new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(!isAppIsInBackgrund(context)){
                        Intent intent = new Intent("APP_MESSAGE_BROADCAST");
                        intent.putExtra("SENDER", msg.getCorrespondent().getId().toString());
                        intent.putExtra("MESSAGE_ID", msg.getId());
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
                    }
                    else {
                        showNotification(msg.getCorrespondent().getName(), msg.getBody());
                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }
}
```

// isAppIsInBackgrund - method where's i check openning app.

```
public boolean isAppIsInBackgrund(Context context){
    boolean isInBackground = true;
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH){
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo:runningProcesses){
            if(processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND){
                for (String activeProcess:processInfo.pkgList){
                    if(activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())){
                        isInBackground = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
        ComponentName componentName = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        if(componentName.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())){
            isInBackground = false;
        }
    }
    return isInBackground; }
```

Comment: are you getting any error or logcat from Firebase ?

Comment: nope, I tried debug but cursor not entering to onMessageReceived

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358462/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-in-background