# Firebase-messaging in background

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-widget

I know that this question is so old and there are a lot of answers on it, but I have not found my decision.

I want to update widget with firebase-cloud-messaging, but Firebase method `onMessageReceived()` is not calling when app is in background.

I've tried to change notification to data as in the most of the answers here, but it not helps me: `onMessageReceived()` is not calling when app is even in **foreground**.

So, my Firebase JSON is:

```
{ "registration_ids": [ "ids" ], 
"priority": "high", 
"content_available": true, 
"data": {
    "id_request": "1229",
    "unreadedAnnouncements": "4",
    "requestsCount": "9",
    "survaysCount": "5", 
    "sound":"default", 
    "title":"test", 
    "message": "test", 
    "body": "test" } }
```

If it matters, my Firebase-dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
```

Maybe there are some new solutions? On the SO there are the most of solutions from 2016.

Comment: can u please revisit this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358462/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-in-background

Comment: @msh.nayan and what? Intent is not my solution (I want to update widget immediately). handleIntent is deprecated. And third solution is here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that is helped me:
In the Firebase I've just changed field `registration_ids` to `to`.

Final Firebase JSON:

```
{ "to": [ "ids" ], 
"priority": "high", 
"content_available": true, 
"data": {
    "id_request": "1229",
    "unreadedAnnouncements": "4",
    "requestsCount": "9",
    "survaysCount": "5", 
    "sound":"default", 
    "title":"test", 
    "message": "test", 
    "body": "test" } }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
{
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    if (remoteMessage.getData() != null)
        sendNotification(remoteMessage);
}
```

then you can parse data like this:

```
    private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
    {
       Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
       String title = data.get("title");
       String content = data.get("content");
       // your code
    }
```

Comment: `onMessageReceived` is not callable for me as I said. But I have no super() method. Can problem be there?

Comment: I think yes. Please try and let us know