# How to read the push Notification data from system tray.?

Tags: android

Is it possible to read the push notification information (Both notification {} and data{} from FCM), without tapping/clicking on the notifications. ?

As for the the Documentation, Notification come your app, either it is in foreground or background, But in these case of background, a notification is delivered to the device's system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

But my requirement is to read the notification without clicking on it.

Is it possible..? if yes please give me some information / some links.

Comment: No, It is not possible to get data from system tray without click on the notification

Comment: Even, i have tried, but not success.

Answer (score -2):

You can use FCM data message instead of notification, everytime you receive a new data message onMessageReceived will be called and you can choose either to show this notification or not, and will get all relevant data.

Comment: you are wrong. When the application is on background the onMessageReceived method is not called.

Comment: If your server is sending you data message then it doesnt matter whether your application is in background or foreground onMessageReceived() will be called read this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358462/firebase-onmessagereceived-not-called-when-app-in-background

Comment: ...  notification messages are delivered to your onMessageReceived callback only when your app is in the foreground. Look at The accepted answer. The other data îs passed to intent în extras parameters

Comment: Read Md. Sajedul Karim's answer where he is defining types FCM.